# error: ‘NULL’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, gcc, pointers, null

I get this message when compiling C++ on gcc 4.3

```
error: ‘NULL’ was not declared in this scope
```

It appears and disappears and I don't know why. Why?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you haven't declared NULL in the scope of where the message is coming from?

Comment: You should atleast post the complete piece of code which is giving the error. Otherwise it will be very difficult to tell what is happening by just looking at the error string.

Answer (score 191, accepted):

`NULL` is not a keyword. It's an identifier defined in some standard headers. You can include

```
#include <cstddef>
```

To have it in scope, including some other basics, like `std::size_t`.

Comment: God, I am so spoiled with Java (null being a keyword) that I never thought that NULL would not be a keyword in c++. Thanks :)

Comment: Actually it's not a keyword in Java either.

Comment: @ManofOneWay No, it exists in Java, it's just spelled with all lowercase instead of capitals.

Comment: @ZettaSuro I didn't say it don't exist. I just said it isn't a keyword.

Comment: Now that C++11 is more generally supported by compilers, it might be worth mentioning the `nullptr` keyword, which is an actual keyword and doesn't require any `#include`s. It's also more typesafe than `NULL`.

Answer (score 39):

GCC is taking steps towards C++11, which is probably why you now need to include *cstddef* in order to use the *NULL* constant. The preferred way in C++11 is to use the new *nullptr* keyword, which is implemented in GCC since version 4.6. *nullptr* is not implicitly convertible to integral types, so it can be used to disambiguate a call to a function which has been overloaded for both pointer and integral types:

```
void f(int x);
void f(void * ptr);

f(0);  // Passes int 0.
f(nullptr);  // Passes void * 0.
```

Comment: But still It is a strange behavior! Even compiling my code with -std=c++98 GCC stills don't recognize NULL macro, and It only recognize nullptr with either c++11 or gnu++11 as argument for -std.

Comment: The C++ standard has stated already in 1998 that NULL is defined in cstddef - the new compiler versions just follow the standard more strictly because they need to implement nullptr. Your (faulty) code has compiled with earlier GCC versions, but it would be difficult to stay backward compatible with earlier GCC versions, in addition to earlier C++ standard versions.

Comment: `NULL` has never been a built-in keyword; it's a macro defined in several standard C headers, including `<stddef.h>` (or `<cstddef>`). How does gcc "taking steps towards C++11" affect this? I see nothing in the question that implies that the (unseen) code compiled with earlier versions of gcc/g++, or with earlier versions of the language standard.

Comment: That's just what I said above: Already in C++98 it was defined in cstddef. Still gcc (and other compilers too) accepted code that used NULL without including cstddef first. I'm quite sure also the (unseen) code in question compiled with earlier versions, even though it's not strictly standard compliant. Now I'm only guessing that this stricter behavior of modern versions is due to development of the compiler to support the C++11 syntax.

Answer (score 10):

`NULL` isn't a keyword; it's a macro substitution for 0, and comes in `stddef.h` or `cstddef`, I believe.  You haven't `#included` an appropriate header file, so g++ sees `NULL` as a regular variable name, and you haven't declared it.

Answer (score 6):

To complete the other answers: If you are using C++11, use `nullptr`, which is a keyword that means a void pointer pointing to null. (instead of `NULL`, which is not a pointer type)

Answer (score 2):

NULL is not a keyword. It's an identifier defined in some standard headers. You can include

```
#include <iostream>
```

Answer (score 1):

NULL can also be found in:

```
#include <string.h>
```

String.h will pull in the NULL from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the error really under certain circumstances can appear and disappear **without changing the code** as stated in the question: "It **appears and disappears** and I don't know why.".

In my case the same happened when compiling the code for ATmega328 using PlatformIO with Visual Studio Code.

For example, if there is `main.cpp` file which includes `Arduino.h` and a header file containing `NULL` then error `'NULL' was not declared in this scope` will **sometimes** appear but sometimes will **not** and build will sometimes be without error but sometimes there will be error.

Sometimes the error `'NULL' was not declared in this scope` will show alongside with the first error but not every time but then suddenly both errors might disappear and build might start working again.

In this case it was enough to copy `#include <Arduino.h>` from `main.cpp` to header file but the question is **why** build **sometimes** work even without including anything into the header file.

Seems as without including the definition at the top of the header file the compiler is not always resolving the symbols in the same order and sometimes the definition of `NULL` is resolved before parsing the code where it is used - but sometimes it isn't.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <something.h>
.
.
.
```

**something.h**

```
.
.
.
Some_class *Ptr = NULL;
```

This code will sometimes generate the error but **sometimes will not.** At least when using VS Code + PlatformIO + target ATmega328.

Answer (score -1):

You can declare the macro NULL. Add that after your #includes:

```
#define NULL 0
```

or

```
#ifndef NULL
#define NULL 0
#endif
```

No ";" at the end of the instructions...

Comment: `NULL` is defined in `<cstddef>` or `<stddef.h>`, and is required by the language standard. Don't define it yourself; just include a header that defines it.

Answer (score -1):

If you look carefully into NULL macro in any std header:

```
#define NULL __null
```

So basically, you may use the `__null` keyword instead.

Comment: `__null` is not a standard keyword. Some compilers may have `__null` as an implementation-defined keyword and define `NULL` as `__null`, but you shouldn't rely on it. (And most standard headers don't define `NULL`, only `<stddef.h>` or `<cstddef>` and any other headers that include them.)