# My Eclipse program dosn't recognize `NULL`

Tags: c++, eclipse, null

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [error: ‘NULL’ was not declared in this scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462165/error-null-was-not-declared-in-this-scope)

i'm having this code, which has been written in visual studio but i`m working in eclipse and i'm trying to make it compilable for eclipse and  i throws me this error

```
..\heap.cpp:104:10: error: 'NULL' was not declared in this scope
```

code:

```
#include"heap.h"

using namespace std;

template<class T>
Heap<T>::Heap() // constructor
{
    root = NULL;
    size = 0;
}
```

Comment: In C++, you should use `0` instead of `NULL`.

Comment: In C++, you should use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`. (;

Comment: `nullptr` if you have the relevant C++11 support, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse isn't a compiler, just an IDE. I'm guessing you're using it with another compiler than Visual Studio and the system headers are somewhat different, leading to your VC++ working includes to not include the declaration of NULL on `<the other compiler>`. As Martinho Fernandes said, you need to include `<stdlib.h>` or `<cstdlib>`, or some header that includes those ones. As the other question says, the C++ 11 way would be `<stddef.h>` or `<cstddef>`.

Comment: Correct as far as finding the correct header for `NULL` goes, but the real C++11 way would be to use `nullptr`.

Comment: Maybe he doesn't have a C++ 11 compiler... who knows.