# C++ use struct defined in another caused endless loop

Tags: c++

Here’s the header file named `Node.h`.

```
struct node{
    int val;
    node *next;
    node(int x){
    val = x;
    next = NULL;
};

void test(){
    node *head = new node(1);
    head->next = new node(1);
    head->next->next = new node(2);
    cout<<head->val;
};
```

And I have a `Test.cpp` file in whose `main` function I called `test()`.

```
#include "Node.h"
int main(){
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

And the output is lldb instead of the node’s value, which should be 1.

Comment: How do you know it's an endless loop? Have you debugged it? Added logging to `node` constructor? Please paste both files as they are when the problem occurs.

Comment: Apparently the main problem is *in the the code you don't show*. Please post a **complete but minimal** example that readers can compile and test, exemplifying the problem. If two source code files are needed, post the source code of both.

Comment: By the way, there's a superfluous semicolon after the closing } of the constructor definition. Technically it's wrong but will probably be accepted (maybe with a warning). Just remove it.

Comment: I dont believe the code you have shown us is causing an endless loop.

Comment: add the `main` function, so maybe something goes wrong there.

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf First of all I do not understand what "Technically it's wrong " means. On the other hand it is a valid definition according to the C++ Standard

Comment: @RichardPlunkett I think it's endless loop since the output is lldb and the program shows it's running,not stopped

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Thanks! I mistakenly thought it was not valid, but there's an optional semicolon after function definition, in the grammar, even in C++98. On the other hand, neither g++ nor visual c++ complain if I add more semicolons, and I can't find that in the grammar.

Comment: the code above doesnt compile.

Comment: @– Cheers and hth. - Alf I think it is chapter 7 where there is said that a declaration can be empty.

Comment: minor edits to compile have this code working for me. If its hanging, you are doing something you arent showing us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in some comments above your code does not compile.

Firstly NULL is not declared until you include certain header files, e.g. `cstddef`
(see [NULL is not declared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462165/error-null-was-not-declared-in-this-scope)).
Also you have to include the `iostream` header in order to use `cout`. Finally you miss one closed curly bracket `}` in Node.h. After these corrections the program outputs 1 as you expected.

Here's the header which compiles:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

struct node
{
  int val;
  node *next;
  node(int x)
  {
    val = x;
    next = NULL;
  } //was missing
};

void test()
{
  node *head = new node(1);
  head->next = new node(1);
  head->next->next = new node(2);
  std::cout<<head->val;
};
```