# error: "null" was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, pointers, null, nodes, singly-linked-list

I am at my wits end trying to debug the above error. I am providing my code below to assist with the troubleshooting process:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Packet
{
    int index;
    string content;

    public:
        Packet()
        {
            index = null;
            content = null;
        }

        Packet(int i, string data)
        {
            index = i;
            content = data;
        }

        void setIndex(int i) {index = i;}
        void setContent(string input) {content = input;}
        int getIndex() {return index;}
        string getContent() {return content;}
};
```

I have tried adding `#include <cstdlib>` (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462165/error-null-was-not-declared-in-this-scope)), `#include <cstddef>`, and manually defining null. Nothing has succeeded. If you can shed light on what I am missing, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for C++ `nullptr` or C `NULL` by any chance?

Comment: @K-ballo, Not quite, because these are being assigned to `int` and `string`.

Comment: `null` isn't a C++ keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to write:

```
    Packet() : index(0), content("") { }
    Packet(int i, string data) : index(i), content(data) { }
```

The word `null` is not reserved by the C++ standard.  `NULL` is a null pointer constant, but is not appropriate as an initializer for `int` (you might get away with it, but it would be equivalent to writing 0, and it is bad practice to use `NULL` where you mean `0` or `'\0'`), and it is not really appropriate to initialize a `string` with `NULL` either.

You could even use:

```
    Packet(int i = 0, string data = "") : index(i), content(data) { }
```

to have a single constructor with defaulted arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read up on memory management in C++.

To take a small sample of your code:

```
class Packet
{
    int index;
    string content;

    public:
        Packet()
        {
            index = null;
            content = null;
        }
```

`index` and `content` are not pointers or references, they are values; it makes no sense to assign `null` to them.

`int index` declares an integer variable called index; the **only** values it can take are numbers in the range representable by `int` on your platform (most likely a 32-bit signed number).

Similarly, `string content` declares a string object, complete with the memory to hold it.  It *must* be constructed (in this case in the `Packet` class constructor).  It makes no sense to try to assign a 'null' value to it.

I'd guess that you are used to writing Java code, where object variables are always references and so can be assigned `null`; that is not true in C++.

The concept of 'null' is a pointer to nothing; in C++ this is written `nullptr` (in C++11) or `0` (in earlier C++ standards); it is common to `#define NULL 0` in those earlier versions.