# Reference on interface as a parameter

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pointer vs. Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114180/pointer-vs-reference)

I am wondering if there any benefits in using references instead of pointers on some interface. Being more specific let's consider small example:

```
struct MyInterface {
   virtual ~MyInterface() {}
   virtual void f() = 0;
};

class MyClass : public MyInterface
{
   virtual void f()
   {
      std::cout << "F()" << std::endl;
   }
};


void myFunction(MyInterface& obj);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   MyInterface* pObj = new MyClass;

   myFunction(*pObj);

   delete pObj;

   getchar();
   return 0;
}

void myFunction(MyInterface& obj)
{
   obj.f();
}
```

In *myFunction* instance of *MyClass* can be passed as a pointer, what is written in many books. My question is what can be considered as a good practice (pointer or reference) and what is more efficient?

Sorry if this question somehow was asked previously.

Comment: With references, you're making it clear to the reader that they can't pass null. There'll be no difference in performance.

Comment: But if 0 is passed as a parameter, this will cause a runtime error, am I wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't the `virtual` be removed at `f` in `MyClass`?

Comment: @besworland, with references, you can't pass 0 at all. With pointers, yes, the code would likely crash when the first virtual function was called.

Comment: @avakar Yeap, just tried it:) Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once a value is passed, passing a reference is, performance wise and semantics wise, the same as passing a pointer.
In the example you wrote, you are passing a reference obtained from a pointer, so the limitations imposed by reference-input function are invalidated here. Indeed, if you wrote

```
MyInterface* pObj = 0;
myFunction(*pObj);
```

You would get a runtime error. But the error is because you are doing

```
myFunction( *0 );
```

i.e., because you are *dereferencing* a null pointer, not because you are *passing* the zero value. In fact,

```
myFunction( 0 );
```

will give you a compile-time exception (which is great).

Answer (score 2):

It depends upon your need.

Use pointer:

- If there's ever a chance that you could want to pass "no object"
- If you want ability to point the passed pointer to different location
- If you want to get address of pointer variable for some reason

else use reference.  A reference is more like a alias to a variable than a pointer to it. This semantics opens some possible optimizations for the compiler and makes it efficient than pointer.

Comment: Good that you mentioned efficiency! That was exactly what I wanted to hear! +1 Thank you.