# Difference between int f(int *i) and int f(int &i)

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the differences between pointer variable and reference variable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c)
>   [Pointer vs. Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114180/pointer-vs-reference)

To do a call-by-reference in C++, I think I could use either of those two:

```
int f(int *x);
int g(int &x);
```

They would be called like so:

```
int *w;
f(w);
g(*w);

int y;
f(&y);
g(y);
```

Is there a difference in the functions `f` and `g`? I should be able to work with `x` as an `int*` pointer and `*x` as an `int` inside both functions. So what is the difference?

Comment: The former is a pointer, the latter is a reference. There is a huge difference between the two. (Also removed the C tag since references don't exist in C)

Comment: This may help you : [differences between pointer variable and reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of this is a matter of taste. There is one important difference though. A pointer (`*`) can have a null value whereas a reference cannot be null and always must refer to a valid object.

Comment: "or null in cpp" what is cpp for you? or did you mean C++ and nullptr?

Comment: yes I meant `nullptr`. I've updated it now

Comment: ...and by cpp/C++ I take it you mean C++11?

Comment: Ok, no reference to individual null values or lanugages any more. Hopefully this should stop any confusion

Answer (score 2):

The reference can't be NULL, so you don't have to check that.  Otherwise, it's probably just syntactic sugar (at least for simple use cases).  Check the disassembly of your program to see.