# C C++ difference between & an *

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the differences between pointer variable and reference variable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c)
>   [Pointer vs. Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114180/pointer-vs-reference)

I recently started to 'relearn' c++ and encountered a simple question that i always had.

```
Int *intp = new int(10);
Int& intref = *intp;
```

intref prints as 10
*intp does so too.

Also do the prints of &intref and intp equal.

Long story short. Is the difference between `&` and `*` simply the way you access the value and adress?
Or is there a major difference in usage?

Comment: Those duplicates are far superior questions. In this one, the example doesn't even compile. And what is "print"? `cout` or `printf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*` notation means what's being pass on the stack is a pointer, ie, address of something. The `&` says it's a reference.

Refer this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c/57492#57492)