# What does 'const&' mean in C++?

Tags: c++, constants, operators, pass-by-reference

Apologies for this, I am a student trying to learn C++ and I just thought it'd be better to ask than to not know.

I understand what the "address of" operator `&` and the `const` keyword mean separately. But when I was reading some sample code I saw `const&`, and I just wanted to know what it means.

It was used in place of an argument in a function prototype, for example:

```
void function (type_Name const&);
```

If only one of them were used I would understand but I am a little confused here, so some professional insight would be great.

Comment: I'm sure someone will shortly provide a thorough answer, but here's a hint:  that's not an address-of operator.

Comment: Please see one of the fine introductory books on the book list: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: Well, I assume you're either learning from a teacher or from a book, both should have the answer.

Answer (score 37):

Types in C++ are read right to left. This is, inconveniently just the opposite direction we like to read the individual words. However, when trying to decide what qualifiers like `const` or `volatile` apply to, putting the qualify always to the right make it easier to read types. For example:

- `int* const` is a `const` pointer to a [non-`const`] `int`
- `int const*` is a [non-`const`] pointer to a `const int`
- `int const* const` is a `const` pointer to a `const int`

For whatever unfortunate accident in history, however, it was found reasonable to also allow the top-level `const` to be written on the left, i.e., `const int` and `int const` are absolutely equivalent. Of course, despite the obvious correct placement of `const` on the right of a type, making it easy to read the type as well as having a consistent placement, many people feel that the top-level `const` should be written on the left.

Comment: Rule of thumb: Read types from RIGHT to LEFT!

Answer (score 23):

In this context, `&` is not an address-of operator.

```
void function (type_Name const&);
```

is equivalent to:

```
void function (const type_Name &);
```

which is nothing but prototype of function taking argument by `const` reference. You should study this kind of topics on your own, ideally from some good book. However, if you're looking for some additional material, these questions might help you too:
[What are the differences between a pointer variable and a reference variable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57483/1168156)
[Pointer vs. Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114180/pointer-vs-reference), [When to use references vs. pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7058339/1168156), [Pass by Reference / Value in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/410593/1168156)