# Getting an optional of a class derived from abstract class, from a class derived from abstract class

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, stdoptional

I have something similar to the code below, where a group of classes with similar shared behaviours (Tool1, Tool2), all inherit from an abstract class (ITool). All these classes own their own optional of a corresponding class (Tool1Attachment, Tool2Attachment), which also inherit from an abstract class (IAttachment).

```cpp
class ITool {
 private:
  virtual ? DoGetAttachment() = 0;
  // Other shared behaviours...

 public:
  ? GetAttachment() {return DoGetAttachment();}
  // Other shared behaviours...
};

class Tool1: public ITool {
  std::optional<Tool1Attachment> opt_attachment;

  ? DoGetAttachment() override;
  
 public:
  [...]
};

class Tool2: public ITool {
  std::optional<Tool2Attachment> opt_attachment;
  
  ? DoGetAttachment() override;
  
 public:
  [...]
};

// --------------------------------

class IAttachment {
  [...]
};

class Tool1Attachment : public IAttachment {
  [...]
};

class Tool2Attachment : public IAttachment {
  [...]
};
```

It makes sense for the tool class to have an optional - in context, it may or may not have an actual instance at any given time.

An issue arises if I have an IAttachment, and would like to get the IAttachment.

I originally used pointers for this, i.e. `IAttachment* GetAttachment();`, which worked "fine". However, it seems to lose some of the more explicit checking of an absent value that optional provides, making it easier to run into nullptr issues in the future.

I also tried different constructs (std::reference_wrapper) with optionals but kept running into invalid covariant errors.

Is there a way of doing this that allows the return of an optional (or similar construct)? What should the return types look like? Or are the pointers with nullptr checks most suitable here?

```
? GetAttachment() {return DoGetAttachment();}
```

Comment: Maybe using a std::unique_ptr is a better model? Could also be that I still don't understand what you are trying to model

Comment: what should `DoGetOwned` return? An copy? A reference? Or should it allow to transfer ownership?

Comment: is it on purpose that `DoGetOwned` is not `const` ?

Comment: *However, it seems to lose some of the more explicit checking of an absent value that optional provides* I'm not sure what do you mean by that. Checking for `nullptr` in pointer is rather similar to checking for `std::nullopt` in `std::optional` (ignoring ownership semantics).

Comment: @PepijnKramer I've updated the question to make it less needlessly abstract.

Comment: please read about [mcve] and try to provide one. If I'd write an answer most effort would need to be put into getting your code to compile (before actually adding something)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I just meant that with optional you can't use the value contained until you explicitly get/check/deref the value, whereas with a pointer to a value you can immediately call methods with ->, which won't complain at compile time.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen just seems to me to communicate that the value is somewhat regularly expected to be absent much better as well

Comment: I think the answer boils down to what you expect of the overriden `DoGetAttachment`s. Should they return an "optional value", propagating the "optionalness" together with the responsibility of value checking to the caller? Should they throw an exception or do something else if the optional is empty?

Comment: @bmetz You can do the same with `std::optional`: https://godbolt.org/z/Wqb84o5dx. I agree that `std::optional` indicates clearly the intent, but well-used pointers do the same if your project correctly uses smart and raw pointers, it's quite clear that pointer means "possibly nullable and possibly derived class" (where reference means "never null and possibly derived class")

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37369429/stdoptional-and-polymorphism

Comment: Is it important to you to get covariant return types? IOW should `Tool1::DoGetAttachment()` be declared as returning `something<IAttachment>` or `something<Tool1Attachment>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer really boils down to what you expect of the `DoGetAttachment` function. Should it *"forward the optionalness"* of the member to the caller, together with the responsibility of checking if the value exists? Or should the `DoGetAttachment` function return a reference if the stored `std::optional` has a value and throw an exception if it doesn't?

Assuming you want to "forward the optionalness" to the caller of the function, you basically have two options.

## Option 1: Use (raw) pointers

Use pointers, as you already have done according to your question. It is the most simple solution and standard practice.

## Option 2: Use `std::optional` together with `std::reference_wrapper`

`std::optional` is not polymorphic, so you cannot cast a `std::optional<Derived>` to an `std::optional<Base>`. What you can do is return an `std::optional<Base*>` or an `std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<Base>>`. IMHO, I would prefer `std::reference_wrapper`, because otherwise you have the "optionalness" property on two levels: Once for the `std::optional` and once for the stored pointer. So you need to check twice for existence.

Option 2 introduces some additional complexity to your code and it is up to you to decide if it is worth it.

Arguments for using `std::optional` are, that

- the "optionalness" of the return value is communicated through semantics. A returned pointer doesn't automatically convey that information;
- returning an `std::optional` allows you to use the monadic operators of `std::optional`, such as `value_or`, `and_then`, `transform` *(some of which are C++23 features)*; and that
- in contrast to owning (raw) pointers, `std::optional`s do not perform any dynamic memory allocation *(if that is something that you need)*.

Here is an implementation, where `DoGetAttachment` returns `std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<IToolAttachment>>`.

```cpp
#include <optional>
#include <iostream>

struct IAttachment {
    virtual ~IAttachment(){}
    virtual std::string foo() const = 0;
};

struct Tool1Attachment : IAttachment 
{ 
    std::string foo() const override { return "Tool1Attachment"; }; 
};
struct Tool2Attachment : IAttachment
{ 
    std::string foo() const override { return "Tool2Attachment"; }; 
};

struct ITool {
  virtual ~ITool(){}

  using IAttachmentCRef = std::reference_wrapper<IAttachment const>;
  virtual std::optional<IAttachmentCRef> DoGetAttachment() const = 0;

};

template <typename T>
struct Tool: public ITool {
  std::optional<T> opt_attachment;

  std::optional<IAttachmentCRef> DoGetAttachment() const override
  {
    return opt_attachment.transform([](auto& v){ return std::ref(v); });
  }
  
};

using Tool1 = Tool<Tool1Attachment>;
using Tool2 = Tool<Tool2Attachment>;

int main()
{
    auto print = [](ITool const& tool) {
        return tool.DoGetAttachment()
            .transform([](auto v){ return v.get().foo(); })
            .value_or("No value.");
    };

    Tool1 tool1;

    Tool2 tool2;
    tool2.opt_attachment = Tool2Attachment();
    
    std::cout << print(tool1) << "\n";
    std::cout << print(tool2) << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
No value.
Tool2Attachment
```

[Live Code Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vfGaEboPe)

Answer (score 2):

A pointer is the obvious solution (with a null pointer if the optional is empty). If you're using inheritance, you'll need a pointer (or a reference) anyway, in order for polymorphism to work, and C++ support covariant return types, so that `Owner1` can return a `Owned1*`. And checking for null on a returned pointer is pretty much standard practice. The alternative would be to return a `optional<IOwned*>` (since covariance won't work here), but I don't see what that would buy you except additional complexity.

Comment: `std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<IOwned>>` would be a possibility, but IMO it doesn't add anything to prefer it over pointer

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Using reference_wrapper would add the possibility to chain functions using the monadic operations `and_then`, `value_or` or `transform` of `std::optional` which have been introduced in C++23. Also, `std::optional` does not use dynamic memory allocation. Finally, "checking for null on a returned pointer is pretty much standard practice" is not a good argument IMHO: I wonder how many bugs out there are caused by an unchecked pointer. Using `std::optional` allone doesn't safeguard against it, but at least it is semantically clear that the value may not be there.

Comment: @joergbrech Returning a pointer doesn't require dynamic memory allocation either, since the member would still be a `std::optional`. And whether you return a pointer or some sort of optional, you have to check validity. (The fact that it's a pointer, and not a reference, makes it semantically clear that the value may not be there.)

Comment: @JamesKanze, I agree and I also agree with your anwer (+1 from me). I just wanted to point out some differences between the approaches which both have pros and cons. According to OP there exists an alternative implementation without `std::optional` based on pointers. Owning (smart) pointers do require dynamic memory allocation. And yes, pointers should always imply that the value may not be there and you have to check before dereferencing. But people use pointers for different reasons. Also in scenarios, where one would expect from context for the value to be there. This is where bugs happen.