# I have a misconception with pointers in C++

Tags: c++, vector

Please find my code-snippet below:

```
void inpu(vector<vector<int>> &pairs,int I){
 //Do something
}

int main() { 
    int I = 10;
    vector<vector<int> > pairs(N);
    inpu(pairs,I);
}
```

Now, I understand that the function `inpu()` expects an address of a vector type and an integer. My doubt is that when calling `inpu()`, why are we not passing an address of the vector `pairs`, as `inpu(&pairs,I);` in `int main()`, but as `inpu(pairs,I);`?

Comment: The `&pairs` **doesn't** mean that the function expects the address of a vector (that would be written as `* pairs`). It's a [pass-by-reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_function_call_by_reference.htm) argument, so it's called as shown.

Comment: &pairs is a pointer. That can be null. `inpu(... &pairs,...)` asks a reference. Not trivial to send in a null. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114180/pointer-vs-reference

Comment: `&` means very different things when used in a type and when applied to an expression as an operator.

Comment: Misconception about what pointers? You aren't using any pointers in the code you show.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I think that is the misconception, that a reference is a pointer. Or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Because you do not pass the object's address (a pointer). You pass the object itself (via a reference). Ampersand in the declaration of function argument is the syntax to distinguish that you want the object itself rather than a copy.

```
// This will copy the pairs
void inpu_c(vector<vector<int>> pairs){
}

// This will work on the original object
void inpu_r(vector<vector<int>> &pairs){
}
```

The pointer can be used as a reference type, you can dereference it and use the original object itself.

```
// This will work on the pointer
void inpu_p(vector<vector<int>>* pairs){
 pairs->clear();
 (*pairs).clear();

 // You can even use a reference type inside, you have to dereference a pointer
 assert(pairs); //Some protection against invalid pointers

 // a reference type requires an object
 vector<vector<int>>& r = *pairs;
 // will clear object pointer by pairs
 r.clear(); 
}
```

Using pass-by-value and pass-by-copy semantics do not change the client syntax though. The client code looks the same. That is why you don't have to use get-address operator (`&`) on the call site.

Pointers are slightly different from references, those two are different data types. E.g. pointer is nullable, i.e. has a special designated invalid value, while reference is designed to always point to an object.