# passing pointers and reference/address of variables in functions

Tags: c++, pointers, pass-by-reference

I would like to know difference between the following 2 functions

```
void fun1(vector<int>&v){  
v.push(1);  
fun1(v);  

}


void fun2(int *sum) 
{
 x=2;
 new_sum=*sum+x;
 fun2(&new_sum);
}
```

I am unable to understand difference. In first function, function declaration has use of pointer and no other place in function body has '&' symbol.
In function 2, function declaration has value at address pointer and function body has '&'. Please explain

like here in below function we use &diagonalsum for passing map why it is used?

```
void diagonalSumUtil(struct Node* root,
            int vd, map<int, int> &diagonalSum)
{
   if(!root)
    return;

diagonalSum[vd] += root->data;

// increase the vertical distance if left child
diagonalSumUtil(root->left, vd + 1, diagonalSum);

// vertical distance remains same for right child
diagonalSumUtil(root->right, vd, diagonalSum);
}
```

Comment: c has no references and there is no function pointer in your code

Comment: `fun2` will never stop recursing.

Comment: @tadman i am only concerned about pointers not about recursion. Pls explain pointers

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Technically `fun2` never starts since it doesn't compile ;)

Comment: You are mistaken. The first example makes no use of pointers. In c++, the same symbol can have different meanings, depending on where it's use. In this case `&` indicates a [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference).

Comment: you are comparing an apple with on orange (both kinda broken btw). If your question is about pointer vs reference why dont you use an example where the difference between two version is only that. Anyhow there should be a duplicate somewhere

Comment: "i am only concerned about pointers" if thats the case, then just use references and forget about pointers for a while ;)

Comment: I am pretty sure OP doesn't realize that `&` in the example above has nothing to do with pointers. May be this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in

Comment: @user463035818 i want to understand the difference not just forget about something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pointer vs. Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114180/pointer-vs-reference)

Comment: You need to read up on pointers and the basics, [this might help](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/)

Comment: well sorry for being sloppy. Of course you should not forget about pointers, the thing is just that pointers are extremely overrated, every newcomer is forced to learn them just to realize later that you rarely need them in c++

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the differences between a pointer variable and a reference variable?](//stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/90527)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ampersand (&) in a declaration declares a *reference type*, not a pointer.

The ampersand (&) in an expression is the *address of* operator, which yields a pointer.

Just because the same token is used in the language for two different things does not mean they are related things.  Unfortunately, especially for learners.