# Is this an inefficent use of casting?

Tags: .net, casting

this question is an extension to a [previous question i asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383857/why-is-this-property-not-getting-set) (and was answered). I'm refactoring my code an playing around with / experimenting with various refactored solutions.

One of the solutions i came up with (but wasn't happy with .. remember, i'm just experimenting with some personal coding styles) wsa the following code :-

```
if (data is ITagElement)
{
    if (((ITagElement) data).TagList.IsNullOrEmpty())
    {
        ((ITagElement) data).TagList = new List<Tag>();
    }

    ((ITagElement) data).TagList.Add(new Tag
    {
        K = xmlReader.GetAttribute("k"),
         V = xmlReader.GetAttribute("v")
    });
}
```

Notice how i'm casting the parent object `data` to the interface type it impliments a number of times? Code works, but i feel like this is code smell -> that it's not very efficient. I feel like this could be cast improved upon - thoughts from any guru's out there?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What about this, so you only do the cast once:

```
ITagElement someData = data as ITagElement
if (someData != null)
{
   if (someData.TagList.IsNullOrEmpty())
    {
        someData.TagList = new List<Tag>();
    }

    someData.TagList.Add(new Tag
    {
        K = xmlReader.GetAttribute("k"),
         V = xmlReader.GetAttribute("v")
    });

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [as operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt(VS.71).aspx) to get is and cast in the same op:

```
ITagElement tagElement = data as ITagElement;
if (tagElement == null) return;

if (tagElement.TagList.IsNullOrEmpty()) {
   tagElement.TagList = new List<Tag>();
}

tagElement.TagList.Add(new Tag
{
    K = xmlReader.GetAttribute("k"),
    V = xmlReader.GetAttribute("v")
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be clearer as such:

```
if (data is ITagElement)
{
    ITagElement dataAsTagElement = (ITagElement)data;
    if (dataAsTagElement.TagList.IsNullOrEmpty())
    {
        dataAsTagElement.TagList = new List<Tag>();
    }

    dataAsTagElement.TagList.Add(new Tag
    {
        K = xmlReader.GetAttribute("k"),
        V = xmlReader.GetAttribute("v")
    });
}
```

This would be better as it's avoiding a cast 3 times in exchange for a pointer.  It's also far easier on the eyes!