# How do pointer-to-pointers work in C? (and when might you use them?)

Tags: c, pointers

How do pointers-to-pointers work in C?
When might you use them?

Comment: No not homework....
just wanted to know..coz i see it a lot when i read C code.

Comment: A pointer to pointer is not a special case of something, so I don't understand what you don't understand about void**.

Comment: for 2D arrays the best example is the command line args "prog arg1 arg2" is stored char**argv. And if the caller doesnt want to allocate the memory ( the called function will allocate the memory )

Comment: You have a nice example of "pointer to pointer" usage in Git 2.0: see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22354860/6309)

Answer (score 404):

Let's assume an 8 bit computer with 8 bit addresses (and thus only 256 bytes of memory). This is part of that memory (the numbers at the top are the addresses):

```
  54   55   56   57   58   59   60   61   62   63   64   65   66   67   68   69
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    | 58 |    |    | 63 |    | 55 |    |    | h  | e  | l  | l  | o  | \0 |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

What you can see here, is that at address 63 the string "hello" starts. So in this case, if this is the only occurrence of "hello" in memory then,

```
const char *c = "hello";
```

... defines `c` to be a pointer to the (read-only) string "hello", and thus contains the value 63. `c` must itself be stored somewhere: in the example above at location 58. Of course we can not only point to characters, but also to other pointers. E.g.:

```
const char **cp = &c;
```

Now `cp` points to `c`, that is, it contains the address of `c` (which is 58). We can go even further. Consider:

```
const char ***cpp = &cp;
```

Now `cpp` stores the address of `cp`. So it has value 55 (based on the example above), and you guessed it: it is itself stored at address 60.

---

As to *why* one uses pointers to pointers:

- The name of an array usually yields the address of its first element. So if the array contains elements of type `t`, a reference to the array has type `t *`. Now consider an array of arrays of type `t`: naturally a reference to this 2D array will have type `(t *)*` = `t **`, and is hence a pointer to a pointer.
- Even though an array of strings sounds one-dimensional, it is in fact two-dimensional, since strings are character arrays. Hence: `char **`.
- A function `f` will need to accept an argument of type `t **` if it is to alter a variable of type `t *`.
- Many other reasons that are too numerous to list here.

Comment: yes good example..i understand what they are..but how and when to use them is more important..now..

Comment: Stephan did a good job reproducing, basically, the diagram in Kernighan & Richie's The C Programming Language.  If you're programming C, and don't have this book and are cool with paper documentation, I highly suggest you get it, the (fairly) modest expense will pay for itself very quickly in productivity.  It tends to be very clear in its examples.

Comment: char* c = "hello" should be const char* c = "hello". Also it's at most misleading to say that "an array is stored as the address of the first element". An array is stored as... an array. Often its name yields a pointer to its first element, but not always. About pointers to pointers, I would simply say that they are useful when a function has to modify a pointer passed as a parameter (then you pass a pointer to the pointer instead).

Comment: @sheepsimulator: That's coincidental then. I did recently buy K&R, but I haven't read up to that point in the book yet :)

Comment: @Bastien: thanks. I updated the text slightly (though one could argue that I now make improper use of the word 'reference'...)

Comment: Unless I'm misinterpreting this answer, it looks wrong. c is stored at 58 and points to 63, cp is stored at 55 and points to 58, and cpp is not represented in the diagram.

Comment: You are right... so many upvotes, and nobody noticed... I'll fix it right away!

Comment: Looks good. Than minor issue was all that was stopping me from saying: Great post. The explaination itself was excellent. Changing to an up-vote. (Perhaps stackoverflow needs to review pointers?)

Comment: Now all the problems that made me retract my upvote are fixed. So i can give you back the vote. Great :)

Comment: Why not say "So if the array contains elements of type t, a reference to the array usually has type t *". That will make it not abuse the word anymore. Or say "So if the array contains elements of type t, a value of that array has type t *" . That's safe to say, since in all contexts that yields a value from an array, that value has type "t*" in C, but not in contexts where a value is not generated (like "sizeof(array)", or "&array).

Comment: @procrastinator: Indeed, fixed it now. (Took me several minutes until I understood what you meant... the mind is a funny thing.)

Comment: @Stephan202 Taken out of context, my question might sound enigmatic indeed :D

Comment: Great visualization, but I think there's some vague expression. _"a reference to the array"_ -> what do you mean by "reference"? And I hope you are not confused about the difference between array and pointer (they are not the same).

Answer (score 54):

**How do pointers to pointers work in C?**

First a pointer is a variable, like any other variable, but that holds the address of a variable.

A pointer to a pointer is a variable, like any other variable, but that holds the address of a variable.  That variable just happens to be a pointer.

**When would you use them?**

You can use them when you need to return a pointer to some memory on the heap, but not using the return value.

Example:

```
int getValueOf5(int *p)
{
  *p = 5;
  return 1;//success
}

int get1024HeapMemory(int **p)
{
  *p = malloc(1024);
  if(*p == 0)
    return -1;//error
  else 
    return 0;//success
}
```

And you call it like this:

```
int x;
getValueOf5(&x);//I want to fill the int varaible, so I pass it's address in
//At this point x holds 5

int *p;    
get1024HeapMemory(&p);//I want to fill the int* variable, so I pass it's address in
//At this point p holds a memory address where 1024 bytes of memory is allocated on the heap
```

There are other uses too, like the main() argument of every C program has a pointer to a pointer for argv, where each element holds an array of chars that are the command line options.  You must be careful though when you use pointers of pointers to point to 2 dimensional arrays, it's better to use a pointer to a 2 dimensional array instead.

Why it's dangerous?

```
void test()
{
  double **a;
  int i1 = sizeof(a[0]);//i1 == 4 == sizeof(double*)

  double matrix[ROWS][COLUMNS];
  int i2 = sizeof(matrix[0]);//i2 == 240 == COLUMNS * sizeof(double)
}
```

Here is an example of a pointer to a 2 dimensional array done properly:

```
int (*myPointerTo2DimArray)[ROWS][COLUMNS]
```

You can't use a pointer to a 2 dimensional array though if you want to support a variable number of elements for the ROWS and COLUMNS.  But when you know before hand you would use a 2 dimensional array.

Answer (score 42):

I like this "real world" code example of pointer to pointer usage, in Git 2.0, [commit 7b1004b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7b1004b0ba6637e8c299ee8f927de5426139495c):

> Linus once said:
>
> > I actually wish more people understood the really core low-level kind of coding. Not big, complex stuff like the lockless name lookup, but simply good use of pointers-to-pointers etc.
> > For example, I've seen too many people who delete a singly-linked list entry by keeping track of the "prev" entry, and then to delete the entry, doing something like:
> >
> > ```c
> >    if (prev)
> >      prev->next = entry->next;
> >    else
> >      list_head = entry->next;
> > ```
> >
> > and whenever I see code like that, I just go "This person doesn't understand pointers". And it's sadly quite common.
>
> People who understand pointers just use a "**pointer to the entry pointer**", and initialize that with the address of the list_head. And then as they traverse the list, they can remove the entry without using any conditionals, by just doing a
>
> ```c
> *pp =  entry->next
> ```
>
> [image: pointers]
>
> Applying that simplification lets us lose 7 lines from this function even while adding 2 lines of comment.
>
> ```
> - struct combine_diff_path *p, *pprev, *ptmp;
> + struct combine_diff_path *p, **tail = &curr;
> ```

---

[Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1198649/chris) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897366/how-do-pointer-to-pointers-work-in-c#comment77036936_22354860) to the 2016 video "[Linus Torvalds's Double Pointer Problem](https://youtu.be/o8NPllzkFhE?t=864)".

---

[kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/124330/kumar) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897366/how-do-pointer-to-pointers-work-in-c/22354860?noredirect=1#comment36251111_22354860) the blog post "[Linus on Understanding Pointers](http://grisha.org/blog/2013/04/02/linus-on-understanding-pointers/)", where **[Grisha Trubetskoy](https://github.com/grisha)** explains:

> Imagine you have a linked list defined as:
>
> ```c
>    typedef struct list_entry {
>        int val;
>        struct list_entry *next;
>    } list_entry;
> ```
>
> You need to iterate over it from the beginning to end and remove a specific element whose value equals the value of to_remove.
> The more obvious way to do this would be:
>
> ```c
>    list_entry *entry = head; /* assuming head exists and is the first entry of the list */
>    list_entry *prev = NULL;
>    
>    while (entry) { /* line 4 */
>        if (entry->val == to_remove)     /* this is the one to remove ; line 5 */
>            if (prev)
>               prev->next = entry->next; /* remove the entry ; line 7 */
>            else
>                head = entry->next;      /* special case - first entry ; line 9 */
>    
>        /* move on to the next entry */
>        prev = entry;
>        entry = entry->next;
>    }
> ```
>
> What we are doing above is:
>
> - iterating over the list until entry is `NULL`, which means we’ve reached the end of the list (line 4).
> - When we come across an entry we want removed (line 5),
> - we assign the value of current next pointer to the previous one,
> - thus eliminating the current element (line 7).
>
> There is a special case above - at the beginning of the iteration there is no previous entry (`prev` is `NULL`), and so to remove the first entry in the list you have to modify head itself (line 9).
>
> What Linus was saying is that **the above code could be simplified by making the previous element a pointer to a pointer rather than just a pointer**.
> The code then looks like this:
>
> ```c
>    list_entry **pp = &head; /* pointer to a pointer */
>    list_entry *entry = head;
>
>    while (entry) {
>        if (entry->val == to_remove)
>            *pp = entry->next;
>        else
>             pp = &entry->next;
>        entry = entry->next;
>    }
> ```
>
> The above code is very similar to the previous variant, but notice how we no longer need to watch for the special case of the first element of the list, since `pp` is not `NULL` at the beginning. Simple and clever.
>
> Also, someone in that thread commented that the reason this is better is because `*pp = entry->next` is atomic. **It is most certainly NOT atomic**.
> The above expression contains two dereference operators (`*` and `->`) and one assignment, and neither of those three things is atomic.
> **This is a common misconception, but alas pretty much nothing in C should ever be assumed to be atomic** (including the `++` and `--` operators)!

Comment: This will help to understand better - http://grisha.org/blog/2013/04/02/linus-on-understanding-pointers/

Comment: @kumar good reference. i have included it in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GiAhUYCUDVc) was essential for me in understanding your example. In particular I was feeling confused (and belligerent) until I drew a memory diagram and traced the program's progress. That said, it still seems somewhat mysterious to me.

Comment: @Chris Great video, thank you for mentioning it! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @VonC This code won’t work **if there are two or more entries which `value(s)` are equal to `to_remove`**. Because after removing the first one, `pp = &entry->next;` is executed when it shouldn’t. Due to this error pp will end pointing to memory location of the next pointer **of the node just deleted** and following delete, `*pp = entry->next;` will be writing the address of the element following the deleted node  (entry->next) to the previously deleted node next pointer severing the **link(s)** in linked list.

Comment: @abetancort Interresting. I suppose when Linus wrote that in 2012 (https://meta.slashdot.org/story/12/10/11/0030249/linus-torvalds-answers-your-questions), he didn't have this particular edge case in mind.

Comment: @VonC What Linus wrote is right, your implementation is missing an else clause before pp = &entry->next; The  entry = entry->next should be outside of the else as its now.

Comment: @abetancort OK. could you edit the answer to include the relevant fix?

Comment: @VonC no problem.

Answer (score 19):

When covering pointers on a programming course at university, we were given two hints as to how to begin learning about them. The first was to view [Pointer Fun With Binky](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/104/). The second was to think about the [Haddocks' Eyes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haddocks%27_Eyes) passage from Lewis Carroll's *Through the Looking-Glass*

> “You are sad,” the Knight said in an anxious tone: “Let me sing you a song to comfort you.”
>
> “Is it very long?” Alice asked, for she had heard a good deal of poetry that day.
>
> “It's long,” said the Knight, “but it's very, very beautiful. Everybody that hears me sing it - either it brings the tears to their eyes, or else -”
>
> “Or else what?” said Alice, for the Knight had made a sudden pause.
>
> “Or else it doesn't, you know. The name of the song is called ‘Haddocks' Eyes.’”
>
> “Oh, that's the name of the song, is it?" Alice said, trying to feel interested.
>
> “No, you don't understand,” the Knight said, looking a little vexed. “That's what the name is called. The name really is ‘The Aged Aged Man.’”
>
> “Then I ought to have said ‘That's what the song is called’?” Alice corrected herself.
>
> “No, you oughtn't: that's quite another thing! The song is called ‘Ways And Means’: but that's only what it's called, you know!”
>
> “Well, what is the song, then?” said Alice, who was by this time completely bewildered.
>
> “I was coming to that,” the Knight said. “The song really is ‘A-sitting On A Gate’: and the tune's my own invention.”

Comment: I had to read that passage a couple of times... +1 for making me think!

Comment: This is why Lewis Carroll is not a ordinary writer.

Comment: So... it would go like this? name -> 'The Aged Aged Man' -> called -> 'Haddock's Eyes' -> song -> 'A-sitting On A Gate'

Answer (score 14):

[Pointers to Pointers](https://web.archive.org/web/20180212053734/http://c-faq.com/%7Escs/cclass/int/sx8.html)

> Since we can have pointers to int, and pointers to char, and pointers to any structures we've defined, and in fact pointers to any type in C, it shouldn't come as too much of a surprise that we can have pointers to other pointers.

Answer (score 11):

A pointer-to-a-pointer is used when a reference to a pointer is required.  For example, when you wish to modify the value (address pointed to) of a pointer variable declared in a calling function's scope inside a called function.

If you pass a single pointer in as an argument, you will be modifying local copies of the pointer, not the original pointer in the calling scope.  With a pointer to a pointer, you modify the latter.

Comment: Well explained for the 'Why' part

Answer (score 11):

**Consider the below figure and program to understand this concept better**.

[image: Double pointer diagram]

As per the figure, **ptr1** is a **single pointer** which is having address of variable **num**.

```
ptr1 = &num;
```

Similarly **ptr2** is a **pointer to pointer(double pointer)** which is having the address of pointer **ptr1**.

```
ptr2 = &ptr1;
```

A pointer which points to another pointer is known as double pointer. In this example **ptr2** is a double pointer.

**Values from above diagram :**

```
Address of variable num has : 1000
Address of Pointer ptr1 is: 2000
Address of Pointer ptr2 is: 3000
```

**Example:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
   int  num = 10;
   int  *ptr1;
   int  **ptr2;

   // Take the address of var 
   ptr1 = &num;

   // Take the address of ptr1 using address of operator &
   ptr2 = &ptr1;

   // Print the value
   printf("Value of num = %d\n", num );
   printf("Value available at *ptr1 = %d\n", *ptr1 );
   printf("Value available at **ptr2 = %d\n", **ptr2);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Value of num = 10
Value available at *ptr1 = 10
Value available at **ptr2 = 10
```

Answer (score 7):

A pointer to a pointer is also called a **handle**. One usage for it is often when an object can be moved in memory or removed. One is often responsible to lock and unlock the usage of the *object* so it will not be moved when accessing it.

It's often used in memory restricted environment, ie the Palm OS.

> [computer.howstuffworks.com Link>>](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/c32.htm)
>
> [www.flippinbits.com Link>>](http://www.flippinbits.com/twiki/index.php?page=handle-vs-pointer)

Answer (score 6):

it's a pointer to the pointer's address value. (that's terrible I know)

basically, it lets you pass a pointer to the value of the address of another pointer, so you can modify where another pointer is pointing from a sub function, like:

```
void changeptr(int** pp)
{
  *pp=&someval;
}
```

Comment: sorry, I know it was pretty bad. Try reading, erm, this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/PtrToPtr.aspx

Answer (score 5):

You have a variable that contains an address of something. That's a pointer.

Then you have another variable that contains the address of the first variable. That's a pointer to pointer.

Answer (score 4):

A pointer to pointer is, well, a pointer to pointer.

A meaningfull example of someType** is a bidimensional array: you have one array, filled with pointers to other arrays, so when you write

dpointer[5][6]

you access at the array that contains pointers to other arrays in his 5th position, get the pointer (let fpointer his name) and then access the 6th element of the array referenced to that array (so, fpointer[6]).

Comment: pointers to pointers should not to be confused with arrays of rank2, eg int x[10][10] where you write x[5][6] you access the value in the array.

Comment: This is only an example where a void** is appropriate.
A pointer to pointer is only a pointer that points to, well, a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

How it works:
It is a variable that can store another pointer.

When would you use them :
Many uses one of them is if your function wants to construct an array and return it to the caller.

```
//returns the array of roll nos {11, 12} through paramater
// return value is total number of  students
int fun( int **i )
{
    int *j;
    *i = (int*)malloc ( 2*sizeof(int) );
    **i = 11;  // e.g., newly allocated memory 0x2000 store 11
    j = *i;
    j++;
    *j = 12; ;  // e.g., newly allocated memory 0x2004 store 12

    return 2;
}

int main()
{
    int *i;
    int n = fun( &i ); // hey I don't know how many students are in your class please send all of their roll numbers.
    for ( int j=0; j<n; j++ )
        printf( "roll no = %d \n", i[j] );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A [5-minute video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3X-ray3tDjQ) explaining how pointers work:

---

[image: pointer buckets]

Answer (score 0):

There so many of the useful explanations, but I didnt found just a short description, so..

Basically pointer is address of the variable. 
Short summary code:

```
     int a, *p_a;//declaration of normal variable and int pointer variable
     a = 56;     //simply assign value
     p_a = &a;   //save address of "a" to pointer variable
     *p_a = 15;  //override the value of the variable

//print 0xfoo and 15 
//- first is address, 2nd is value stored at this address (that is called dereference)
     printf("pointer p_a is having value %d and targeting at variable value %d", p_a, *p_a);
```

Also useful info can be found in topic [What means reference and dereference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224831/meaning-of-referencing-and-dereferencing/14224977)

And I am not so sure, when can be pointers useful, but in common it is necessary to use them when you are doing some [manual/dynamic memory allocation- malloc, calloc, etc.](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-dynamic-memory-allocation)

So I hope it will also helps for clarify the problematic :)