# scanf_s throws exception

Tags: windows, exception, visual-c++

Why does the following code throw an exception when getting to the second `scanf_s` after entering an number to put into the struct.

This by no means represents a complete linked list implementation.

Not sure how to get onto the next `scanf_s` when having entered the value? Any ideas?

EDIT: Updated code with suggested solution, but still get an `AccessViolationException` after first `scanf_s`

Code:

```
struct node
{
    char name[20];
    int age;
    float height;
    node *nxt;
};

int FillInLinkedList(node* temp)
{

int result;
temp = new node;

printf("Please enter name of the person");
result = scanf_s("%s", temp->name);

printf("Please enter persons age");
result = scanf_s("%d", &temp->age); // Exception here...

printf("Please enter persons height");
result = scanf_s("%f", &temp->height);

temp->nxt = NULL;
if (result >0)
    return  1;
 else return 0;
}

// calling code

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
  node temp;

  FillInLinkedList(&temp);

...
```

Comment: You are using managed code, why are you messing with scanf()?  Use Console::ReadLine(), int::TryParse() and List<node>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need

```
result = scanf_s("%d", &temp->age);
```

and

```
result = scanf_s("%f", &temp->height);
```

Reason is that `sscanf` (and friends) requires a *pointer* to the output variable so it can store the result there.

BTW, you have a similar problem with the parameter `temp` of your function. Since you're changing the pointer (and not just the contents of what it points to), you need to pass a double pointer so that the changes will be visible outside your function:

```
int FillInLinkedList(node** temp)
```

And then of course you'll have to make the necessary changes inside the function.

Comment: @Martin: Funny you mention pointer to pointers, that's the whole reason I was attempting to write this, is to learn about pointers to pointers, seems I haven't fully got the idea yet...

Comment: @Tony: Take a look at this question -- the highest voted answer has quite a good description: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897366/how-do-pointer-to-pointers-work-in-c

Answer (score 5):

You are using scanf_s with incorrect parameters.  Take a look at the examples in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et%28VS.80%29.aspx) for the function.  It requires that you pass in the size of the buffer after the buffer for all string or character parameters. So

```
result = scanf_s("%s", temp->name);
```

should be:

```
 result = scanf_s("%s", temp->name, 20);
```

The first call to scanf_s is reading garbage off the stack because it is looking for another parameter and possibly corrupting memory.

There is no compiler error because scanf_s uses a variable argument list - the function doesn't have a fixed number of parameters so the compiler has no idea what scanf_s is expecting.

Comment: A horrible decision from microsoft.

Comment: it is also good practice to include a width specifier on the %s. scanf_s("%19s", temp->name, 20);

Answer (score 2):

scanf() stores data into variables, so you need to pass the address of the variable (or its pointer)
Example:

```
char string[10];
int n;
scanf("%s", string); //string actually points to address of
                     //first element of string array
scanf("%d", &n); // &n is the address of the variable 'n'
```

Answer (score 1):

- `%19c` should be `%s`
- `temp->age` should be `&temp-age`
- `temp->height` should be `&temp->height`
- Your compiler should be warning you
  about these errors

Comment: Did you make all 3 of the above changes ?

Comment: When you test are you entering less than 20 characters for the name ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to pass parameters to scanf() functions by address. i.e. &temp->age

otherwise temp-age will be interpreted as a pointer, which will most likely crash your program.