# C program returning array

Tags: c

I am working on a very basic program where I want to return an integer array of length 2 to my main block. I can't get it to work though, and I was told that I may need pointers to do this. How do pointers work, and how can I use this in my program?
Here is my current code:

```
int[] return2();


int main() {

  int a[2];

  a = request();
  printf("%d%d\n", a[0], a[1]);


  return(0);
}

int[] request ()
{
  int a[2];

  a[0] = -1;
  a[1] = 8;

  return a;
}
```

Comment: sorry - "request" should say return2

Comment: If you want to know how pointers work, why not try Googling it?

Comment: Yes, you will need an understanding of pointers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897366/how-do-pointer-to-pointers-work-in-c

Comment: (1) learn pointers (2) if you still want to do this as a by-val result, then stuff the result content in a custom struct, which you *can* return by-value. Thats your call.

Answer (score 6):

- You can't declare a function returning an array.

  > #### ISO/IEC 9899:1999
  >
  > #### §6.9.1 Function definitions
  >
  > ¶3 The return type of a function shall be `void` or an object type other than array type.

  C2011 will say essentially the same thing.
- You shouldn't ever return a pointer to a (non-static) local variable from a function as it is no longer in scope (and therefore invalid) as soon as the return completes.

You can return a pointer to the start of an array if the array is statically allocated, or if it is dynamically allocated via `malloc()` et al.

```
int *function1(void)
{
    static int a[2] = { -1, +1 };
    return a;
}

static int b[2] = { -1, +1 };

int *function2(void)
{
    return b;
}

/* The caller must free the pointer returned by function3() */
int *function3(void)
{
    int *c = malloc(2 * sizeof(*c));
    c[0] = -1;
    c[1] = +1;
    return c;
}
```

Or, if you are feeling adventurous, you can return a pointer to an array:

```
/* The caller must free the pointer returned by function4() */
int (*function4(void))[2]
{
    int (*d)[2] = malloc(sizeof(*d));
    (*d)[0] = -1;
    (*d)[1] = +1;
    return d;
}
```

Be careful with that function declaration!  It doesn't take much change to change its meaning entirely:

```
int (*function4(void))[2]; // Function returning pointer to array of two int
int (*function5[2])(void); // Array of two pointers to functions returning int
int (*function6(void)[2]); // Illegal: function returning array of two pointers to int
int  *function7(void)[2];  // Illegal: function returning array of two pointers to int
```

Comment: +1 : Didn't know that static can be used in functions. I thought that it can only be used in classes(C++).

Comment: This is C, not C++.  I hope the "Don't know" is really "Didn't know", and that now you do know.  In fact, you can use `static` like that (inside a function) in C++ too.

Answer (score 3):

You better to understand how does pointer work. Here is a (bad) solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int* request(){
    int a[2];
    a[0] = -1;
    a[1] = 8;
    return a;
}

int main() {
    int* a;
    a = request();
    printf("%d%d\n", a[0], a[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

but there is a problem. since `int a[2];` in `int* request()` is a local variable, there is no guarantee that the value returned will not be overwritten.
Here is a better solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void request(int* a){
    a[0] = -1;
    a[1] = 8;
}

int main() {
    int a[2];
    request(a);
    printf("%d %d\n", a[0], a[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to return `pointer to array of 2 integers` from function.
    #include

```
int(* request()) [2]
{
static int a[2];
a[0] = -1;
a[1] = 8;
return &a;
}

int main() {
int (*a) [2];
a = request();
printf("%d%d\n", *(*a+0), *(*a+1));
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You'd have to return `&a`, wouldn't you?  And you've got the pointer to a local (non-static) array problem...

Comment: I seems that returning `a` is right. `a` is a pointer already. EDIT: tested. You better to return `a` . returning `&a` generates a compiler warning.

Comment: @CarealManic: did you try compiling the code?  The name `a` is an array; when it is used in `return a;`, it returns a pointer to the first element of the array (an `int *` in this context), which is quite different from a pointer to an array (`int (*)[2]`) — even though the address returned, viewed as a `void *`, is the same.

Comment: never mind. I have misread the code. I thought that it's `int* request()` .

Comment: @CarealManic , this is the error i get when i compile the above program          error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘)’ token

Comment: @Barath Bushan ,it was my mistake try to compile now,I had made changes.

Comment: I have never seen a function that return a pointer to int[2] . :S Oh well, it works, so whatever. :P

Comment: @HiteshMenghani , when executed , it displays -1 & 0 , not -1 & 8

Comment: @Barath Bushan,I didn't run it.Now try latest.

Comment: @HiteshMenghani , very complicated and less readable/maintainable way to write code , which could have been written by much simpler means. But +1 for getting it working....

Comment: @Barath Bushan ,yes it is complex but it will work quite well when you have to return multiple values from function.

Answer (score 1):

The array `int a[2]` that you declare in `request` is only valid during the scope of that function, so returning it like that doesn't work, since once `main` gets its hands on it the array is no longer valid.

If you don't understand pointers, you're going to kind of have to to really get what's going on, but here is some code that will do what you want:

```
int* request();

int main() {

  int* a;  // a is a pointer to an int

  a = request();
  printf("%d%d\n", a[0], a[1]);

  // we have to tell the program that we're done with the array now
  free(a);

  return(0);
}

int* request ()
{
  // allocate space for 2 ints -- this space will survive after the function returns
  int* a = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);/

  a[0] = -1;
  a[1] = 8;

  return a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do as others suggest and allocate memory via malloc to return a pointer.  You should also consider something like the following:

```
struct values {
    int val1;
    int val2;
};

struct values request();

int main() {

  struct values a;

  a = request();
  printf("%d%d\n", a.val1, a.val2);

  return(0);
}

struct values request ()
{
  struct values vals;

  vals.val1 = -1;
  vals.val2 = 8;

  return vals;
}
```

Structures are passed and returned by value (meaning they are copied) and can sometimes be easier and safer depending on the type of data contained within the structures.

Answer (score 0):

To return the array, you must dynamically allocate it.

Try this instead (Observe the changes) :

```
int* request();

int main() {    
  int *a;    
  a = (int *)request();
  printf("%d %d\n", a[0], a[1]);        
  return(0);
}

int* request() {
  int *a = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);    
  a[0] = -1;
  a[1] = 8;    
  return a;
}
```

Comment: Or return a pointer to statically allocated memory...