# Using managed and owned pointers together

Tags: rust

I'd like to understand the meaning of the following code snippet from ["12 Dereferencing pointers"](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/tutorial.html#dereferencing-pointers) of Rust tutorial:

```
let point = &@~Point { x: 10f, y: 20f };
println(fmt!("%f", point.x));
```

Especially, what does @~ mean?

Answer (score 2):

It is simply an application of multiple pointer-taking operators. You can put braces to see it clearer (though I don't know whether it is valid Rust code):

```
&(@(~Point { x: 10f, y: 20f }))
```

This is really a borrowed pointer to a managed box which contains unique pointer to a struct.

Such thing, of course, is useless in real code but it demonstrates dereferencing concept.

Comment: "pointer-taking" == pointer *making* for `~` and `@`: they allocate space on the heap. (And that code is perfectly valid.)

Answer (score 1):

The expression is a reference to a managed pointer to an owned pointer to a Point.

The sentence above gives a good hint:

> You can write an expression that dereferences any number of pointers automatically. For example, if you feel inclined, you could write something silly like

It's simply to demonstrate that you can have a pointer to a pointer to something. The code is certainly silly in that this snippet doesn't make good use of the concept, it's simply to show off the syntax.

For more on pointers to pointers, you might enjoy this question: [How do pointer to pointers work in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897366/how-do-pointer-to-pointers-work-in-c)