# Passing a matrix of structs to a function in C

Tags: c, matrix, struct

I know there are similar questions, but I still can't figure this out, even though I've been reading for 2 hours.

```
struct box 
{ 
    char letter; 
    int occupied; //0 false, 1 true. 
}; 

void fill(struct box**, int, int, char*);  //ERROR HERE**


int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{ 
    int length=atoi(argv[4]), 
        width=atoi(argv[5]), 

    char alphabet[26] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"; 
    struct box soup[length][width]; 
    fill(soup, length, width, alphabet);  //HERE**
}

void fill(struct box soup[][], int length, int width, char*alphabet) //AND HERE**
{
   //omitted 
}
```

These are the errors I'm getting when I compile:

```
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘fill’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]  
     fill(soup, length, width, alphabet);  
     ^  

note: expected ‘struct box **’ but argument is of type ‘struct box (*)[(sizetype)(width)]’  
void fill(struct box **, int, int, char*);  
     ^  

error: array type has incomplete element type  
void fill(struct box soup[][], int length, int width, char*alphabet)
                     ^
```

I don't get why that fails, while some other functions I have like this one, does work:

```
void wordsToMemory(char**, char*);   //prototype
char* dictionary[Nwords];            
wordsToMemory(dictionary, argv[1]);  //calling the method
void wordsToMemory(char* dictionary[], char* argv) //function body
{
 //omitted
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897366/how-do-pointer-to-pointers-work-in-c

Answer (score 0):

This will get it to compile:

```
void fill(struct box** soup, int length, int width, char* alphabet)
```

or

```
void fill(struct box* soup[], int length, int width, char* alphabet)
```

When using `[][]` you get an error because there is no conversion from `struct box*` to `struct box`.

Comment: You must have a strange compiler that accepts a function argument of type _array of `length` arrays of `width` `struct box`_ for a formal parameter of type _pointer to pointer to `struct box`_ - or you just didn't try to compile it.

Answer (score 0):

`Array decays into pointers.` When you are passing a single dimension array to a function, the function which receives the array can look like this

```
void fun(char a[10])    void fun(char a[])  void fun(char *a)
{                       {                   {
    ...             OR      ...         OR      ... 
}                       }                   }
```

`Arrays decays into pointer, not always true`...Arrays decay into pointers is not applied recursively...Means, `2D` Array decays to `pointer to array` not to `pointer to pointer` so that is why you are getting the error.

When you are passing `2D` array to function, the function which receives the `2D` array should look like this...

```
void fun(char *a[10])
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: While the answer's main part is right, the last block isn't; the function rather is `void fun(char (*a)[10])` or `void fun(char a[][10])`.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> void fill(struct box**, int, int, char*);
> ```

This declaration is wrong because it says that the function's first argument has to be of type *pointer to pointer to `struct box`*, while you have no objects of type *pointer to `struct box`* in `main` to refer to, rather you have, as you say, a matrix (a two-dimensional array, an array of arrays) of structs.

So, the prototype

```
void fill(struct box [][], int, int, char *);
```

is almost correct, except, only the major (the first) dimension of a matrix declaration can be omitted, so we need to specify at least the `width` therein, which conveniently is also passed to the function, only the parameters' order has to be changed so that `width` is defined early enough:

```
void fill(int length, int width, struct box soup[][width], char *alphabet);
```

The function call in `main` is consequently:

```
    fill(length, width, soup, alphabet);
```