# Why do I have an error in the pointer in C?

Tags: c

I am starting to learn pointers in C.

Why do I have an error in line 8 at `&i`?

*This is the source:*

```
char * func(char *d, char *str) 
{
    return d;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *i = NULL;
    func(&i, "aaa"); // line 8. here I have the error (in "&i")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `&i` is not `char *` it is `char * *`.

You should go through this 
[How do pointer to pointers work in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897366/how-do-pointer-to-pointers-work-in-c)

Comment: What is the difference between them?

Comment: One is a pointer to char and another is a pointer to pointer to char.

Answer (score 3):

You are passing `char**` and the function expects a `char*`. You need to pass `i` without the address of & operator, because this way you are taking the address of the pointer.

Just pass     `func(i, "aaa");`

Answer (score 1):

When you write `&i`, you are passing the memory address of `i`, but since `i` is already a `char*`, the type of `&i` is `char**` (pointer to pointer to char). You therefore have an extraneous `&` that is causing a type mismatch. Simply remove the `&` and pass `i` to the function with taking its address:

```
func(i, aaa); //no need to use & on a variable that is already a pointer
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your function prototype `func(char *d, char *str)` first parameter accepts pointer of `char` type and in `char *i;` `i` is a pointer of char type so pass it directly to function.

If you want to pass `&i` to the function you need to have `pointer to pointer variable` that is `char **d`.