# Problems about C program char * pointer

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

There is a simple C program.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *s = "abcde";
    printf("%s\n", s);

    printf("%s\n", *s); /* This is wrong */
    return 0;
}
```

This is my thought:

1. variable `s` is a `char *` pointer to the string `abcde`. So variable `s` is a memory address , and the memory address store the string `abced`.
2. The `%s` format string in function `printf()` is formatting a string. I don't know why `s` is the string. The variable `s` is a `char *` pointer and `*s` is the string of `abcde`, isn't it?

Comment: "I don't know why s is the string" - The `%s` is replaced by your argument and, well... s stands for string I assume.

Comment: a `char` is a character, not a string. A `char *` is an array of characters, aka a string.

Comment: The memory address stores `a`. The next memory address stores `b` and so on. `s` points to the `a`.

Comment: The confusing thing is that C really has no such thing as a "string".  Rather, you pass a `char*` pointer with the understanding that it points to a byte that is the start of a sequence of bytes (in successively higher address slots) that ends with a byte with a zero (numeric) value.  The `%s` format code understands this "understanding".

Comment: @RedAlert - A `char*` is a pointer to a character -- that's all it's defined to be.  It *may* point to an array of `char`, or it *may* point to a "string", or it *may* simply point to a single character, but that's all up to the programmer to keep track of.

Comment: @RedAlert, Please don't say a pointer is an array. It causes way too much confusion. Arrays are different types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C, "strings" are [NUL-terminated arrays of characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string).

The code `char *s = "abcde";` does two things:

First, it allocates (in read-only program data) some (unnamed) memory, and populates it with `"abcde"`:

```
 1000   1001   1002   1003   1004   1005
 _________________________________________
|  a   |  b   |  c   |  d   |  e   |  \0  | 
|______|______|______|______|______|______|
```

Then, in the stack frame of `main`, a *pointer to `char`* is allocated, named `s`, and its value is initialized with the *address* of your string. In my example, `s = 1000`.

```
 1000   1001   1002   1003   1004   1005
 _________________________________________
|  a   |  b   |  c   |  d   |  e   |  \0  | 
|______|______|______|______|______|______| 

   ^
   |
   |
 s = 1000
```

The `%s` format specifier tells `printf` to expect the address of a NUL-terminated string as the corresponding argument..

**When you pass `s`**, you are doing just that: telling `printf` that your string lives at address 1000.  `printf` goes to that address, and starts reading the characters there (`a`, `b`, `c`...) until it encounters a NUL (`'\0'`) character, at which point it stops. It has now read your string.

**When you pass `*s`**, two things happen. First, the program de-references the pointer. Since it is a pointer-to-char, that means it reads one character from the memory at 1000.  The result of this is `'a'`, which is the decimal number 97.  Now, this value is passed to `printf` (as before), and `printf` still thinks it's an address. However, 97 is an invalid address, and your program crashes.

If you need to brush up on your understanding of pointers:

- [How do pointer to pointers work in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897366/how-do-pointer-to-pointers-work-in-c)
- [Everything you need to know about pointers in C](http://boredzo.org/pointers/)
- [Pointer Basics](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/106/)

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is my thought: 1. `char *s` is a memory address(such as 1000) that point to char `a`, so the address of `1000` stores a char named 'a'. 2. The result is char `a` when I use `printf("%c", *s)`. My string lives at address `1000` until it ends of `\0` when I use `printf("%s", s)`. Does my thought right? Thank you

Comment: There was a [suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4807954), IMO valid, that got rejected.

Comment: If one uses `%*s`, then there are not even as many format specifiers as there needs to be arguments ;)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Thanks for pointing that out. I agree, and made the edit.

Answer (score 2):

> and *s is the string of abcde, isn't it?

No. `*s` is a `char`, the first `char` in the string, so it's `a`.  `*(s + 1)` is `b`, `*(s + 2)` is `c`, and so on.  A `char*` is an address which *points*, or refers, to some number of `char`s.

You are lying to `printf` with that second call and invoking undefined behavior.  The character `a` is passed and interpreted as an address using it's integral value.  That's going to lead to bad things.

`printf` expects a pointer to `char` when you use the `%s` format specifier and that's what you have to pass it. So, what ends up happening is that `printf` reads past `(char*)'a'` looking for a null terminator.  It may or may not find one before segfaulting, but it's UB either way.

Turn your warnings on.

Answer (score 0):

In c, a string is just a string of characters in memory terminated with a null character (`'\0'`) which tells you where the string stops. *There are no string objects*. As such when you provide a 'string' to `printf` you pass it a pointer to where the string is held and it figures out the rest.

Answer (score 0):

when printf meet with a string , It automatically put out the string from start address "a" to the end "\0"; This is special. While printf deal with string, it obey this rule. And for a string, "*a" is the first character of the string , not the whole string . So when you want to put out a string , give the start address to printf. "*a"."*(a+1)"...can help you put out the character you want in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Q: The variable s is a char * pointer and *s is the string of abcde, isn't it?

No.

`*s` is a specific character pointed to by `s`.  In the question code, it is the character 'a'.

If it helps, `*s` results in the same character as `s[0]`.  In otherwords, (for the question code) `*s` is the value of the first character in the array (or string) of characters.

---

On the other hand, `s` is a `char *` that can store an address.  It can store any address in memory you like.  In the question code, `s` was initialized to point at a specific static string (or array of characters).

You can print the specific address pointed to by `s`:

```
printf("s points to %p\n", s);
```

You can print the specific character pointed to by `s`:

```
printf("The character pointed to by s: %c\n", *s);
```

You can print the string (or array) of characters pointed to by `s`:

```
printf("s points to an array of characters: %s", s);
```