# Seg fault error?

Tags: c, arrays, string, segmentation-fault, void

Does anyone know why I keep getting this seg fault error?
I am trying to run a program that locates a substring "from" within "src" and replaces all non-overlapping occurrences of "from" in src with "to" in the output string "dest".
Also, could anyone provide me with the proper way to test this case? As I'm not too sure how I could display this with type "void"... (Trying this as an exercise)

```
void find_replace(char* src, char* from, char* to, char* dest)
{
  int count = 0;
  int diff = strlen(to) - strlen(from);
  int destlength = strlen(src);
   dest = malloc(destlength);
  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(src); i++)
    {
      int index = 0;
      while (src[i+index] == from[index] && index < strlen(from)){
        index++;
      }
      if (index == strlen(from)) {
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(to); j++) {
          dest[i+j+(count * diff)] = to[j];
        }
        i += strlen(from) - 1;
        count++;
      }
      else {
        dest[i + (count * diff)] = src[i];
      }
    }
  return ; 
}
```

Is it sufficient enough to do this for a test?

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
     char* dest;
   find_replace("hello my name is leeho lim", "leeho lim", "(insert name)" dest);
  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(dest); i++)
    {
      printf("%c", dest[i]);
    }
  printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: string literals are not modifiable in C.

Comment: Yea, I realized that, but I don't think that's the source of my seg fault

Comment: Suspect all warnings are not enabled.  Suggest -Wall

Comment: You are Replacing more text than you have originally, thus the size of DEST is too small.  You need to allocate the size to Dest more precisely.

Comment: Fixed all the suspected warnings from -Wall, but it still persists... initialized the char* dest at the end (suspected that might do something)...
I also changed the "to" input to be less than the "from" input, but the seg fault still persists ):

Comment: (RESOLVED) I initialized my char * dest with the strlen(src) in the main function and ran it.

Comment: That solves one problem, but you still are accessing the destination buffer outside its bounds if the replacement is longer than the substring to replace.  Such cases definitely invoke undefined behavior.  If you're lucky, that will manifest in the form of segfaults.

Comment: Note, too, that `strlen(src)` is anyway not enough space even if the replacement string doesn't appear at all in the source string -- you need space for a string terminator.

Answer (score 1):

The problems happens because you are trying to access an unallocated pointer with

```
strlen(dest)
```

In the for in your main program.

The reason for this is that you sent the value of the pointer `dest` to the function, not the pointer itself, so when you allocated the memory inside your function, so you didn't actually modify the memory address stored in the pointer outside of it.

When you send the pointer as a parameter of a function, what you are actually doing is sending the memory address stored in that pointer, you are sending the value stored in the pointer, not the pointer itself.

If you want to get the allocated memory address for the string, you either can make the function return it, or you can declare and send `dest` as a [pointer to a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897366/how-do-pointer-to-pointers-work-in-c).

EDIT: As the other comment points out, you can also perform the allocation in `main()`, instead of doing it inside your function.

Answer (score 0):

A few minor tweaks to your program is all you need.

Change the return value of `find_replace` to be the newly allocated memory for the changed string.

Instead of

```
void  find_replace(char* src, char* from, char* to, char* dest)
```

Use

```
char* find_replace(char* src, char* from, char* to)
```

Change the implementation slightly.

Instead of

```
  dest = malloc(destlength);
```

use

```
  char* dest = malloc(destlength);
```

and

Instead of

```
  return;
```

use

```
 return dest;
```

Change the way you use the function.

Instead of

```
char* dest;
find_replace("hello my name is leeho lim", "leeho lim", "(insert name)", dest);
```

use

```
char* dest = find_replace("hello my name is leeho lim", "leeho lim", "(insert name)");
```

Make sure to deallocate memory returned by `find_replace`.

```
free(dest);
```

Here's a fully working program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* find_replace(char* src, char* from, char* to)
{
  int count = 0;
  int diff = strlen(to) - strlen(from);
  int destlength = strlen(src);
  char* dest = malloc(destlength);
  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(src); i++)
    {
      int index = 0;
      while (src[i+index] == from[index] && index < strlen(from)){
        index++;
      }
      if (index == strlen(from)) {
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(to); j++) {
          dest[i+j+(count * diff)] = to[j];
        }
        i += strlen(from) - 1;
        count++;
      }
      else {
        dest[i + (count * diff)] = src[i];
      }
    }
  return dest; 
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   char* dest = find_replace("hello my name is leeho lim", "leeho lim", "r sahu");
   for (int i = 0; i < strlen(dest); i++)
   {
      printf("%c", dest[i]);
   }
   free(dest);
   printf("\n");
}
```

**Update, in response to OP's comment**

If the return type of `find_replace` must be `void`, there are couple of options on how to deal with the memory needed for `dest`.

1. Allocate memory for `dest` in the calling function.

   ```
   char* dest = malloc(SUFFICIENT_SIZE);
   find_replace("hello my name is leeho lim", "leeho lim", "(insert name)", dest); 

   free(dest);
   ```

   Then, there is no need for the line

   ```
   dest = malloc(...);
   ```

   in `find_replace`.
2. Allocate memory for `dest` in `find_replace`. Then, you need to pass a pointer to a pointer.

   ```
   void find_replace(char* src, char* from, char* to, char** dest)
   ```

   and use `*dest` instead of just `dest` in the function.

   ```
   void find_replace(char* src, char* from, char* to, char** dest)
   {
     int count = 0;
     int diff = strlen(to) - strlen(from);
     int destlength = strlen(src);
     *dest = malloc(destlength);
     for (int i = 0; i < strlen(src); i++)
       {
         int index = 0;
         while (src[i+index] == from[index] && index < strlen(from)){
           index++;
         }
         if (index == strlen(from)) {
           for (int j = 0; j < strlen(to); j++) {
             (*dest)[i+j+(count * diff)] = to[j];
           }
           i += strlen(from) - 1;
           count++;
         }
         else {
           (*dest)[i + (count * diff)] = src[i];
         }
       }
     return; 
   }
   ```

   and change the you call `find_replace`.

   ```
   char* dest;
   find_replace("hello my name is leeho lim", "leeho lim", "(insert name)", &dest);
   ```

Comment: See, I'd change the output to be a char*, but just for practice, my teacher wants me doing it with a void output. But thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

There are two main problems with your (original) code:

1. it does not provide for your `find_replace()` function to return the allocated destination buffer to the caller, and
2. it does not reliably allocate enough space for the destination buffer.

In principle, issue (1) could be resolved in two ways.  Either the space could be allocated by the caller and a pointer to it passed to the function, or the space could be allocated by the function and a pointer returned to the caller.  Your original code allocates space in the function, *but does not return a pointer to it to the caller*.

It is preferable for the function to perform the allocation, because satisfying issue (2) requires a more thorough analysis of the inputs than makes sense to insist the caller perform.  Consider what happens in your revised code when you do this:

```
char dest[4];
int canary = 0;

find_replace("aaa", "a", "longer string", dest);
assert(canary == 0);
```

Most likely you get a segfault, possibly you get an assertion failure, and perhaps you get who-knows-what, because `find_replace()` cannot perform its job without writing past the end of `dest`, the result of which is undefined.

Although you've said the exercise requires your function to have no return value (i.e. `void`), it can still return a pointer to the destination string via the argument list.  You simply pass a *pointer* to the `dest` pointer instead of its value, so that the function can update that value.  The signature would look like this:

```
void find_replace(const char *src, const char *from, const char *to,
                  char **dest_p);
```

(Note the `const` qualifers for `src`, `from`, and `to`, which are appropriate, if not necessary, if the function is meant to accept string literals.)

The amount of space needed for `dest` is the length of `src` plus one for the terminator plus, if `to` is longer than `from`, the difference between the lengths of the `to` and `from` strings times the number of appearances of the `to` string.  You could, however, compute an upper bound on that length, and later shrink the allocation (if needed) after you find out how much space is actually used.  For example:

```
void find_replace(const char *src, const char *from, const char *to,
                  char **dest_p) {
    ssize_t src_size = strlen(src);
    ssize_t from_size = strlen(from);
    ssize_t to_size = strlen(to);
    char *temp;

    if (!from_size) {
         /* special case: the 'from' string is empty ... */
         /* whatever you do, set temp to something valid or NULL */
    } else {
        ssize_t size_diff = to_size - from_size;

        if (size_diff < 0) size_diff = 0;
        temp = malloc(1 + src_size + (src_size / from_size) * size_diff);
        if (temp) {
            /* use next to track the next unused position in temp */
            char *next = temp;

            /*
             * perform the substitution, updating 'next' appropriately as
             * you go along (INSERT CODE AFTER THIS COMMENT) ...
             */

            /* be sure to terminate: */
            *(next++) = '\0';

            /* shrink the string to the actual space used (optional): */
            next = realloc(temp, next - temp);

            /*
             * On (re)allocation error, next will be NULL and temp will still
             * be a valid pointer.  Otherwise, next will be a pointer to the
             * space, not necessarily equal to temp, and temp might no longer
             * be a valid pointer.
             *
             * An OK error recovery strategy is to just return a pointer
             * to the full-size space.
             */
            if (next) {
                temp = next;
            }
        } /* else allocation failure; return NULL */
    }

    /*
     * The caller gets a pointer to the allocated space (if any).  It is his
     * responsibility to free it when it is no longer needed.
     */
    *dest = temp;
}
```

The actual substitution code is left as an exercise, since this **is** homework, after all.