# C double pointer meaning

Tags: c, linked-list, double-pointer

I cannot understand the meaning of a C code about linked lists that is using double pointers. Here is the code I am reading

```
    struct list
{
    int value;
    struct list *next;
};
//Insert an element at the begining of the linked list
void insertBegin(struct list **L, int val)
{
    //What does **L mean?
    //Memory allocation for the new element temp
    struct list *temp;
    temp = (struct list *)malloc(sizeof(temp));
    //The new element temp points towards the begining of the linked list L
    temp->next = *L;
    //Set the beginning of the linked list
    *L = temp;
    (*L)->value = val;
}
void loop(struct list *L)
{
    printf("Loop\n");
    //Run through all elements of the list and print them
    while( L != NULL )
    {
        printf("%d\n", L->value);
        L = L->next;
    }
}
struct list* searchElement(struct list *L,int elem)
{
    while(L != NULL)
    {
        if(L->value == elem)
        {
            printf("Yes\n");
            return L->next;
        }
        L = L->next;
    }
    printf("No\n");
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    struct list *L = NULL;
    insertBegin(&L,10); // Why do I need 
    return 0;
}
```

What does `**L` in the `insertElement` mean and what is the difference between the `**L` and the `*L` in the `loop` function?  Why in the main when `struct list *L = NULL` is declared I should call the function `insertBegin` with the argument `&L` and not a simple `L`?

I guess `*L` is a pointer towards the first node of the linked list while `**L` may point toward any element of the list. However, I am not sure this is correct.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/897414/2318775

Comment: `temp = (struct list *)malloc(sizeof(temp));` --> `temp = malloc(sizeof *temp);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a function to write to a parameter and have that new value reflected in the caller, then you must pass a pointer for that parameter:

```
void foo( T *p ) // for any type T
{
  *p = new_value(); // write a new value to the thing p points to
}

void bar( void )
{
  T var;
  foo( &var ); // foo writes a new value to var
}
```

If we substitute `T` with a pointer type `Q *`, then the code is

```
void foo( Q **p ) // for any type Q
{
  *p = new_value(); // write a new value to what p points to
}

void bar( void )
{
  Q *var;
  foo( &var ); // foo writes a new value to var
}
```

The semantics in both cases are exactly the same; we want `foo` to update the value stored in `var` through the pointer `p`.  The only difference is that in the second case `var` already has a pointer type, so `p` has to be a pointer to that pointer type.

In the code you posted, the `insertBegin` function updates the value stored in `L`, which is a pointer to the head of the list.  Since the variable `L` in main has type `struct list *`, the type of the *parameter* `L` in `insertBegin` needs to be `struct list **`.

Answer (score 2):

It means "pointer to a pointer". In C pointers are passed by value, so if you want to be able to modify a pointer passed to a function outside of that function, you have to pass a pointer to it. Passing the pointer will only pass another value for it, which will be modified in the function but will not reflect a change to the value outside of it. Passing as a pointer to pointer essentially allows you to modify the value at the address passed rather than just to modify the local.

Consider those two functions:

```
void foo(int * p, int * t) {
  p = t;
}

void foo2(int ** p, int * t) {
  *p = t;
}
```

And the code:

```
int a = 1, b = 2;
int * p = &a;

foo(p, &b);
// in foo *p == 2, but here *p is still == 1, because p didn't change, only the copy that was passed to foo changed
foo2(&p, &b); // now *p == 2, p was changed in foo2
```

Answer (score 1):

The type `**L` is read as pointer to a pointer to L.  So if you have a pointer to an L and takes its address, that is what you get.   The pattern of `**L` in a function argument (in C) is usually used to implement an "out parameter" - a parameter the code can update. To insert at the beginning, you need to update the pointer to the head of the list - that is why that function takes a pointer to the head as a parameter.  When assigning to `*L`, the function updates the parameter.

Comment: What does *L point to? To the head of the list? 
If yes, it seems to me that you don't really need to use the **L pointer, you could directly change the adress contained in the *L pointer.

Comment: A memory location that can hold a pointer to L.  Basically it has  the address of  a variable or member of type pointer to L.

Answer (score 1):

L stores address of the first link in the list.  Thus:
*L is *contents* of the first link in the list, and
&L is the *address of the variable* that stores the address of the first link in the list.

In other words, your only way to allocate memory for and initialize a list by passing the argument into a function is by providing &L as an argument.  If you pass L as an argument, the function will receive the address of the first link, whereas instead it needs a place where to *store* the address of the first link.

Comment: So you want to modify the adress of the first node, in other words *L. To change *L, you need to use a pointer to *L. That's why we should use the **L? Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

The double pointer in insertBegin is for when you are changing the location of L from where ever L is to the node you are inserting. When calling the function you need &L because you need to pass it by reference because you are changing L