# Initializing a table of GtkWidget* in C

Tags: c, pointers, gtk, side-effects

I'm writing a simple C app with GTK2.

I have a little problem - I must create a `9x9` table of entry widgets, so I think it is a good idea to create an array of `GtkWidget`s and use it in loops etc.

But... my program crashes when I pass an element of this array to a GTK function.

I declare the array like this:

```
GtkWidget* entries[9][9];
```

later, I have a function:

```
void drawBoard(GtkWidget* table, GtkWidget* entries[][9])
{
    for(last_i=1; last_i<10; last_i++)
    {
        for(last_j=1; last_j<10; last_j++)
        {
            addField(entries[last_i-1][last_j-1],table);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally in `addField` I use the entry like this:

```
void addField(GtkWidget* field, GtkWidget *table)
{
    field = gtk_entry_new_with_max_length(1);
    //rest of code
}
```

Afterwards, when I try to access the elements I initialized in the code above, the program crashes, for example:

```
void function(GtkWidget *entries[][9])
{
    int i,j=0;
    for(i=0; i<9; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<9; j++)
        {
            gtk_entry_set_width_chars(entries[i][j], 2);//<-- here app crashes
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the value of `i`, `j` when it crashes?

Comment: mh. Please post a MWE we can run in `gdb`, you got me curious.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Gw6WpiMS - it crashes on line, when I'm trying to run function with entries[0][0] element, line 51. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Unless* I'm wrong, you do not seem to be initializing `entires` anywhere.
As a result, in

```
addField(entries[i][j],table,i,j);
```

I *think* you are passing a bunch of completely random pointers that result in segfaulting.

Try initializing `entries` first, e.g.:

```
for(i=0; i<9; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<9; j++)
    {
        entries[i][j] = gtk_label_new ("button");
        addField(entries[i][j],table,i,j);
        fprintf(stderr,"%d %d",i,j);
    }
}
```

---

EDIT: You mention in your comment that you initialize it in `addField`.

I had not noticed it, in fact *I hadn't bothered to look for initialization inside `addField`* (for reasons that will be soon apparent).

My bad.

Let's see what's going on.

You are creating your object inside the scope of `addField` and assigning it to the pointer `GtkWidget* field`.

Nice, but is the *pointer* `GtkWidget* field` passed by value or by reference?

By value, so what you do inside `void addField` has *no effect* on the value of `entries[i][j]`.

If you carried out operations on a (pre-existing) object, without changing *the value of the pointer*, yes - that's pretty much what pointers are good for -, but if you are changing the value of the pointer *itself*, no.

So [you need to pass a **pointer to pointer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897366/how-do-pointer-to-pointers-work-in-c), something to the effect of

```
void addField(GtkWidget** field, GtkWidget *table, int i, int j)
{
    *field = gtk_entry_new_with_max_length(1);
    gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE (table), *field, j, j+1, i, i+1);
    gtk_widget_show (*field);
    gtk_entry_set_width_chars((GtkEntry*)*field, 2);
    gtk_widget_modify_font(*field, pango_font_description_from_string("Tahoma 25.4"));
    g_object_set_data(G_OBJECT(*field), "i", last_i);
    g_object_set_data(G_OBJECT(*field), "j", last_j);
    g_signal_connect (*field, "insert-text",
                      G_CALLBACK (edited_callback),
                      *field
                     );

}
```

and of course

```
        addField(&entries[i][j],table,i,j);
```

This can get pretty ugly, however, so you may want to simply initialized it *outside*.

Comment: I initialize entries in function addField - in first line `field = gtk_entry_new_with_max_length(1);` field is pointer to entries[i][j], or not?

Comment: @blidea: glad I could help. Pointers in C can sometimes be tricky. Make sure you completely understand the basics before moving on to GTK development. And even then consider PyGTK :P

If this has helped you consider also upvoting and accepting it as an answer. 

Good luck :)

Comment: @blidea: I just realized that there is something very wrong with your idea that "`field` is pointer to `entries[i][j]`". In fact *they are both pointers to some object in the heap*.