# What does a pointer to a pointer mean?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have often seen c++ programs with a pointer to a pointer variable i.e  **i. What does it mean and why is it used. Cant we just use a single pointer instead of that. What is the difference between a single pointer and a pointer to a pointer. Please explain each step. Thank you.

Comment: each step of what? and a pointer to a pointer is just a normal pointer. its a pointer that just happens to point to something pointing to a block of memory

Comment: what's the diff between a postit that says "socks are under the bed", and a post-it that says "directions to socks are on post-it on fridge"?

Comment: Imagine an array. An array is a pointer to a bunch of items in a row. Now imagine a pointer to an array - that's a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: a very common example is a 2D array or array of strings (char*)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do pointer to pointers work in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897366/how-do-pointer-to-pointers-work-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables take up some space to store. This space is taken from memory. Suppose your stack (memory) starts at `0x12 34 56 78`and you have an integer `a` with value `4`:

```
int a = 4;
```

Your memory might look like:

```
0x12 34 56 78: 0x00 00 00 04 (a)
```

Now suppose you also have a pointer to `a`:

```
int a = 4;
int* p = &a;
```

Your memory would then look like:

```
0x12 34 56 78: 0x00 00 00 04 (a)
0x12 34 56 7c: 0x12 34 56 78 (p)
```

Now suppose you have a pointer to `p`:

```
int a = 4;
int* p = &a;
int** q = &p;
```

Your memory would then look like:

```
0x12 34 56 78: 0x00 00 00 04 (a)
0x12 34 56 7c: 0x12 34 56 78 (p)
0x12 34 56 80: 0x12 34 56 7c (q)
```

You can get from `q` to `p` to `a` by following the addresses. Pointers are a layer of indirection: they specify where something is, not what it is.