# Convert two dimensional array to a one dimension by using pointer in C language

Tags: c

I wanted to convert two dimensional array to a one dimension (array linearization ) by using a pointer and setting it to a particular character.
Here is the code:

```
#define COLS 20
#define ROWS 10

void convert(void)
{

    char record[ROWS][COLS] = { 0 };

    char *pRecord = record;

    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < (ROWS*COLS); i++)
    {
        *(pRecord++) = ' ';

    }

}
```

However, I am getting a compiler error in initializing the pointer to `char` array.  I 'vd edited the code i.e it will be *pRecord, previously it was only pRecord. Need some help in understanding the error and if possible some suggestions to fix it.

Comment: `char pRecord = record;`...how exactly?

Comment: You are trying to set a `char` pointer to a `char`. Try: `char* pRecord = record`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May I suggest you define the pointer as a pointer?  This compiles cleanly on my machine:

```
char *pRecord = &record[0][0];
```

Comment: That is exactly the same effect as saying `char *pRecord = record;` :)

Comment: @mikeyq6 You should get a type warning for that. Luckily char* can alias that, but other types can't.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is implementing the equivalent of `memset(record, ' ', sizeof(record))`. A manual implementation would roughly look like:

```
char *pRecord = (void *)record;
size_t len = sizeof(record);
while (len--) *pRecord++ = ' ';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to  *Convert two dimensional array to a one dimension*, check this  idea:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define COLS 20
#define ROWS 10

void convert(void)
{
   int i,j;
   char  *pRecord ;
   char newArray [COLS * ROWS];
   pRecord  = newArray;
   char record[ROWS][COLS] = { 0 };

    for ( i = 0 ; i <  ROWS ; i++)
      for ( j = 0; j < COLS ; j++){
        *pRecord = record[i][j]; 


      }

}
```

Maybe this post will serve [How do pointer to pointers work in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897366/how-do-pointer-to-pointers-work-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

```
char (*pRecord)[COLS];
pRecord = record;
```

Though, in the case of array, that will turn out in this way.

```
pRecord == *pRecord
```