# How to print pointer to pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I am a newbie trying to understand the working of double pointers and to print double pointers. I increment `m` by one but it's always pointing to the last value pointed by `p`. Can someone please help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
   /* an array with 5 elements */
   double balance[5] = {1000.0, 2.0, 3.4, 17.0, 50.0};
   double *p;
   double **m;
   int i;

   p = balance;
   m = &p;
   /* output each array element's value */
   printf( "Array values using pointer\n");

   for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
     printf("*(p + %d) : %f\n",  i, *(p+i) );
   }

   for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
     printf("**(m + %d) : %f\n",  i, *m);
     m++;
   }

   printf( "Array values using balance as address\n");

   for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
      printf("*(balance + %d) : %f\n",  i, *(balance + i) );
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do pointer to pointers work in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897366/how-do-pointer-to-pointers-work-in-c)

Comment: double-pointer and pointer to pointer are supposed to mean different things!!!

Comment: Funny: Your explanatory printf text is "**(m + %d)" but you actually pass only `*m` (not `**m` as you should)! Accordingly, you must increment `*m`, i.e. `p`, and not `m` proper which should continue to point to `p`.

Comment: Why do you need the pointer-to-pointer for in the first place? It fills no purpose in this program.

Comment: @ Lundin I have a bigger program which require pointer to pointer for using a library. I wrote it in simpler program to understand how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array `balance` is like this

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 1000.0 |    2.0 |    3.4 |   17.0 |   50.0 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

After you initialize `p` and `m` it is like this:

```
+---+
| m |
+---+
|
v
+---+
| p |
+---+
|
V
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 1000.0 |    2.0 |    3.4 |   17.0 |   50.0 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

That is, `m` points to the location of `p`, and `p` points to the first value of the `balance` array.

When you dereference `m` (i.e. when you do `*m`) you get the value of where `m` is pointing. This value is *another* pointer (`p`) that you need to dereference to get to an element in the array.

Using `m` the second element in `balance` (i.e. `balance[1]`) is `(*m)[1]`.

---

Now if you increment `m` (with e.g. `m++`) it will point to the next element of `p`:

```
     +---+
     | m |
     +---+
     |
     v
+---+
| p |
+---+
|
V
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 1000.0 |    2.0 |    3.4 |   17.0 |   50.0 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

You can clearly see the problem here: It no longer points to `p` and you can no longer us it to access the `balance` array. Dereferencing `m` after the increment will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Also, for *any* pointer or array, the array-indexing expression and the pointer arithmetic expression are equal. So for `balance`, the expression `balance[i]` is equal to `*(balance + i)`. There is really no difference between them.

Answer (score 0):

So after you execute

```
double balance[5] = {1000.0, 2.0, 3.4, 17.0, 50.0};
double *p;
double **m;

p = balance;
m = &p;
```

the following are all true:

```
  m == &p                     // double **
 *m ==  p == &balance[0]      // double *
**m == *p ==  balance[0]      // double

(*m)[i] == p[i] == balance[i] // double
```

Remember that the expression `a[i]` is defined as `*(a + i)`; given the address `a`, offset `i` elements (**not bytes**<sup>1</sup>) from that address and dereference the result.

This means that `*p` is equivalent to `*(p + 0)`, which is equivalent to `p[0]`.  Thus, you can use `p[i]` in place of `balance[i]`.  Since `*m == p`, you can also use `(*m)[i]` in place of `p[i]`.  The parentheses are necessary - unary `*` has lower precedence than postfix `[]`, so `*m[i]` would be parsed as `*(m[i])`, which is not what you want here.

You can increment `p` directly to "walk" through the `balance` array:

```
p = balance; // p == &balance[0];
for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
  printf( "%f\n", *p++ );
```

Each time through the loop, `p` is incremented to point to the next element of `balance`.

You can do something similar with the expression `(*m)`:

```
p = balance; // p == &balance[0]
m = &p;      

for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
  printf( "%f\n", (*m)++ );
```

Again, the parentheses around `*m` are necessary; since postfix `++` has higher precedence than unary `*`, the expression `*m++` would be parsed as `*(m++)`, which is not what we want.  We don't want to change the value of `m`, we want to change the value of what `m` *points to*, which in this case is `p`.

Now, suppose we leave `p` out of the picture completely; can we do something like:

```
double balance[5] = { ... };
double **m;

*m = balance;
```

No.  In this example, `m` is an *invalid* pointer; it hasn't been initialized to point anywhere meaningful, so `*m` will invoke undefined behavior (which can include, but is not limited to, a segfault).  `m` *has* to point to an object of type `double *` before you can dereference it.  There has to be a middleman like `p` in order for that scheme to work.

---

1. Pointer arithmetic always takes the size of the pointed-to type into account - if `a` points to an object of type `T`, then `a + 1` yields the address of the next object of type `T`, which may be more than 1 byte away from the current address.