# Bridging Header Method Parameter Issue

Tags: objective-c, swift, bridging-header

I'm trying to learn how to use Bridging Headers in this test project. For this part, I want to have a method where it takes in and returns a CGPoint array.

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>

    @interface OpenCVWrapper : NSObject

    + (UIImage *)grayscaleImage:(UIImage *)image;
    + (UIImage *)gaussianBlurImage:(UIImage *)image;
    + (UIImage *)cannyEdgeImage:(UIImage *)image;

    //Error says Expected a type
    + ([CGPoint *])lineEdges:([CGPoint *])points;

    @end
```

Because I'm new to this, I don't know where to even start looking for a problem.

Comment: Bridging header is not something you write manually. How is your `OpenCVWrapper` is defined? Swift class or Objective-C class?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand your question (I'm still new to this). I think that OpenCVWrapper is an Objective-C **interface**. I'm using the OpenCV framework, which I believe is in c++.

Comment: You write Objective-C interface in combination with Objective-C implementation. The interface is needed to write the implementation, not for the bridging header. Or else when you write a Swift class, Xcode generates a bridging header. Have you written that `OpenCVWrapper` is an Objective-C class in the text of your question?

Comment: Yes, I understand what you mean. OpenCVWrapper is an Objective-C class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to return an array of CGPoint, your array should hold a NSValue type, because the array cannot hold struct type

```
+ (NSArray<NSValue *> *)lineEdges:(NSArray<NSValue *> *)points;
```

and you should call your method as

```
NSArray *lineEdges = [OpenCVWrapper lineEdges:@[[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(3.3, 4.4)]]];
```

The return value also should be in NSValue and extracting

```
NSValue *val = [lineEdges objectAtIndex:0];
CGPoint p = [val CGPointValue];
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. Also, I've been seeing the asterisk symbol a lot in some sample code. I've read that its a pointer, whose value is actually a reference to a location. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes thats correct. For more details on pointers you can go through this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897366/how-do-pointer-to-pointers-work-in-c/897414. 
Also please mark the answer as accepted, so that it may help others identify the right working solution