# What's the difference between Single pointer and Double pointers for array of strings

Tags: c

I have checked a lot of sources, but I didn't understand what's the difference between single pointer and double pointers exactly, like when I use *string, I can fill it with many strings, and when I use **string, I can do the same thing.

Can any one give me a simple example that could make me understand ?, and how can I use malloc for both of them?.

Comment: You should include some example code. Your description is a bit unclear to me at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

** is a pointer to an existing pointer *
I would review this link for a detailed explanation
[How do pointer to pointers work in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897366/how-do-pointer-to-pointers-work-in-c)

For malloc, there are plenty of examples on this site