# Error in printing the value of a pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers

I had to print the value of a pointer:

```
int *p = 0;
printf("%d", *p);
```

The code above throws an exception.

So I tried `printf("%d", p)` and that worked.

Why did it work only without the `*`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do pointer to pointers work in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897366/how-do-pointer-to-pointers-work-in-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you derefererence the pointer `p` (as `*p`) you dereference a null pointer (you try to get the value where `p` is pointing, but it's not actually pointing anywhere). This leads to *undefined behavior* and very often a crash.

When you use plain `p` you print the contents of the pointer variable itself, not the value of where it's pointing. But that *also* leads to undefined behavior, because the `%d` format is to print an `int` value, not a `int *` value. Mismatching format specifier and argument type is UB.

Comment: @G0rdo1 He's pretty well known around here

Comment: Just to complement the answer: the correct format specifier to print a pointer is `%p`, not `%d`