# Why cant assign a numeral to a *P?

Tags: c

I am a new learner for c.
And I met with this ERROR.

```
int *p;
*p=6;//ERROR
int a=6;
*p=a;//Right
```

Could you please explain this situation? Thank you very much!

Comment: What did you think `p` pointed to? What error do you get?

Comment: check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897366/how-do-pointer-to-pointers-work-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

Both example are incorrect.

Before you can dereference a pointer, you need to make it point someplace.  For example:

```
int *p;
int a;
p = &a;
a = 5;
printf("*p=%d\n", *p); // prints *p=5
a = 6;
printf("*p=%d\n", *p); // prints *p=6
```