# C programming parameters

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>


void getScores(int a, char n[10][15], int s[10]) {
    int score;
    printf("Enter the number of students: ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    for (int i=0; i < a;i++)
    {
            scanf("%s",n[i]);
            scanf("%d",&score);
            s[i]=score;
    }
}

void printScores(int a, char n[10][15], int s[10] ) {
    for (int i=0; i < a;i++)
    {
            printf("%s", n[a]);
            printf(" ");
            printf("%d\n",s[a]);
    }

}

int main() {
    char names[10][15];
    int scores[10];
    int num;


    getScores(num,names,scores);
    printScores(num,names,scores);
}
```

What I am trying to accomplish is have the parameter value of `int a` from the `getScores` function to be used in the `printScores` function as an array length as it is being used in `getScores`.

The arrays are saving its value when used in the print function but the `a` value is resetting to an unassigned number 896 when I need it to be what the user enters in the get function. Any tips?

Comment: Post sample user names.

Comment: Ted 10, Mark 55

Comment: In main(), neither of those function calls can change the argument 'num':(  It remains uninitialized in the printScores() call.

Comment: [How do pointer to pointers work in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/897366/10147399)

Comment: but why if the names and scores change the num doesnt?

Comment: The parameter `a` in your `getScores()` function is local to the function.  Changes made in the function do not affect the value or variable named when the function is called.  The obvious way to deal with it is to make the function return the number of values: `int getScores(char n[10][15], int s[10]) { int a; …; return a; }`.  The alternative is to make the argument into a pointer: `void getScores(int *a, char n[10][15], int s[10])` and then pass `&num` in the `main()` function, and inside `getScores()`, pass `a` (and not `&a`) to `scanf()` and reference `*a` when you need the number.

Answer (score 0):

1. Print scores will not print anything.
2. 

```
void getScores(int *a,
```

And the call

```
getScores(&num
```

You need also change accordingly the functions code

Comment: ..or return it as a function result.

Comment: He wants parameter. Let's be parameter