# Need clear understanding why value isn't affected even if passed by reference?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, function-pointers

I have a question on which I seek clarity with pointers. I am coming from javascript so I am having a hard time with pointers. I have written singly linked list code mostly by myself and the code is fully working. I have created a function to delete the particular item in the linked list. The function in the main is this:

```
insertAtMiddle(&head, 3, 500);
insertAtMiddle(&head, 100, 500);
```

There is one thing I can't understand. First I would like to show the code of my delete function.

```
void insertAtMiddle(node_t **head, int location, int newData){
    node_t *temp = *head;

    while(temp->next != NULL){
        if (temp->data == location)
        {
            break;
        }
        //Shouldn't that also change the original head or move the head to the left as it is passed by reference
        temp=temp->next;
    }

    if (temp->data != location)
    {
        printf("No location found for replacement!");
    }

    //Create new node 
    node_t *newNode = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    newNode->data = newData;

    newNode->next = temp->next;
    temp->next = newNode;
}
```

My question is shouldn't the temp=temp->next; inside the while loop should also affect or modify the original head? Head has been passed as a reference to this function. My confusion arises because *temp = *head, temp has been assigned head.

My full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} node_t;

void viewAllNodes(node_t *head){
    node_t *tmp = head;

    printf("\n");

    while (tmp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d--->", tmp->data);
        tmp=tmp->next;
    }

    printf("\n");
}

void insertAtBegining(node_t **head, int data){
    node_t *tmp = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    tmp->data = data;
    tmp->next = *head;
    *head = tmp;
}

void deleteNode(node_t **head,int data){
    
    node_t *tmp = *head, *nodeToDelete = NULL;

    //see two nodes in advance
    while(tmp->next != NULL){

        if (tmp->next->data == data)
        {
            nodeToDelete = tmp->next;
            break;
        }
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }

    if (nodeToDelete == NULL)
    {
        printf("No node found to delete");
        return;
    }
    
    tmp->next = nodeToDelete->next;
    free(nodeToDelete);
}

void insertAtEnd(node_t **head, int data){
    node_t *newNode = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    node_t *tmp = *head;
    
    while (tmp->next != NULL)
    {
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }

    tmp->next = newNode;
}

node_t *searchNode(node_t *head, int value){
    node_t *tmp = head;

    while (tmp->next != NULL)
    {
        if(tmp->data == value){
            return tmp;
        }
        tmp=tmp->next;
    }
    
    return NULL;
}

void insertAtMiddle(node_t **head, int location, int newData){
    node_t *temp = *head;

    while(temp->next != NULL){
        if (temp->data == location)
        {
            break;
        }
        //Shouldn't that also change the original head as it is passed by
        temp=temp->next;
    }

    if (temp->data != location)
    {
        printf("No location found for replacement!");
    }

    //Create new node 
    node_t *newNode = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    newNode->data = newData;

    newNode->next = temp->next;
    temp->next = newNode;
}

int main(){

    node_t *head = NULL;

    insertAtBegining(&head, 1);
    insertAtBegining(&head, 2);
    insertAtBegining(&head, 3);
    insertAtBegining(&head, 4);
    insertAtBegining(&head, 5);
    insertAtBegining(&head, 6);

    insertAtEnd(&head, 8);
    insertAtEnd(&head, 9);

    insertAtBegining(&head, 100);
    viewAllNodes(head);
    
    deleteNode(&head, 1);
    deleteNode(&head, 8);

    insertAtMiddle(&head, 3, 500);
    insertAtMiddle(&head, 100, 500);

    viewAllNodes(head);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You never modify `*head`. `temp` is just a local copy of `*head`.

Comment: `head` still points to where it was pointing before. `temp` initially points to where `head` is pointing and later updates when `temp = temp->next`.

Comment: @kiner_shah shouldn't change head because temp has been assigned as  *temp = *head; Any modifications made to temp should also affect head?

Comment: What is the type of `head` on this line: `insertAtMiddle(&head, 3, 500);`?

Comment: Pointers also occupy some memory. `node ** head` in `insertAtMiddle` is a pointer to a location where pointer to `head` is stored.

Comment: One important thing about pointers is that they are also values, the memory location where the point to, in C arguments are passed by value, so if you pass a pointer as argument of a function, it is still a copy of the original value, changing it does not change the original. This is not really the main problem here, but it is something that helps to understand the dynamic.

Answer (score 2):

You are basically doing this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int* head) {
  int temp = *head;
  temp = 1234;
}

int main()
{
  int bar = 0;
  foo(&bar);
  printf("bar = %d\n", bar);
}
```

You expect `1234` as output, but the actual output is `0`.

`temp` is just a local copy, modifying `temp` will just modify `temp` and nothing else.

Comment: Can you help me understand what is still causing this? https://onlinegdb.com/MX1oFcg83

Comment: @killerprince182 you should ask a new question

Comment: @killerprince182 quick answer: you never modify `a` and there is no pointer to `a` either so how should `a` be modified?

Comment: @killerprince182 [here you have some pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/897366/6865932) (pun intended) on how pointers work, note that this does not at all replace the learning process you should take on, I'm an old fashioned guy so I think you should start by getting yourself a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/562303/6865932).