# Why does theis recursive function not work?

Tags: c, recursion, reverse, doubly-linked-list, function-definition

I am trying to write a recursive function to reverse a doubly linked list. This code is not complete yet but I am hit with a issue. The application is not executing completely.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct nodes
{
    uint8_t x;
    struct nodes *next;
    struct nodes *prev;
}Node;

Node *head = NULL;

void rev_rec_dll(Node **a, Node **b)
{
        //check if it is last node in the list
    if((*a)->next != NULL)
    {
                //set next to prev and prev to next
        (*a)->next = (*a)->prev;
        (*a)->prev = (*b);
        printf("done for node %d and moving on..\n", ((*a)->x));
        //recursive call by passing next two nodes
                rev_rec_dll(b, &((*b)->next));
    }
    else
    {
        printf("reached new head\r\n");
        head = (*a);
    }
}

void add_node(Node **h_node, uint8_t x)
{
        //check if there is at least one node in the list and if not add first node
    if((*h_node) == NULL)
    {
        *h_node = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        (*h_node)->x    = x;
        (*h_node)->next = NULL;
        (*h_node)->prev = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        Node *temp = *h_node;
        //get the last node
        while(temp->next != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        //add new node
        Node *newNode = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        
        newNode->x      = x;
        newNode->next   = NULL;
        newNode->prev   = temp;
        
        temp->next      = newNode;
    }
}

void display_nodes(Node *h_node)
{
    while(h_node != NULL)
    {
        printf("Node: %u\n", h_node->x);
        h_node = h_node->next;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        //add three nodes
    add_node(&head, 1);
    add_node(&head, 2);
    add_node(&head, 3);

    //display nodes
    display_nodes(head);

        //add three more nodes
    add_node(&head, 4);
    add_node(&head, 5);
    add_node(&head, 6);

        //display all 6 nodes
    display_nodes(head);
    
        //reverse the linked list
    rev_rec_dll(&head, &(head->next));

        //display reversed nodes 
    display_nodes(head);
    
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the program is given below:

```
Node: 1
Node: 2
Node: 3
Node: 1
Node: 2
Node: 3
Node: 4
Node: 5
Node: 6
done for node 1 and moving on..
```

I want to know what is wrong in the function `rev_rec_dll()`. Also, I want to know if the way I am passing the arguments to this function is correct or not. If it is not correct please provide appropriate reason on why it is wrong. The arguments passed to rev_rec_dll function is current node and next node in the linked list.

The reversing logic may not be accurate but I want to know if the way the arguments are passed is correct. Why does it exit in the middle? A memory violation?

Comment: [don't cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Use a debugger to see what's going on. Or draw all the list elements on a piece of paper and pretend to be the computer executing it.

Answer (score 2):

For starters it is a bad idea to declare the pointer to head node as a file scope variable and when the functions depend on the file scope variable.

```
Node *head = NULL;
```

You should move this declaration inside the function `main` and correspondingly rewrite your functions.

Also the structure declaration will look better if to declare it like

```
typedef struct Node
{
    uint8_t x;
    struct Node *next;
    struct Node *prev;
} Node;
```

Otherwise the names `nodes` and `Node` will only confuse readers of the code.

There are two problems with the function. The first one is that initially the second function argument points to the data member `next` of the head node

```
rev_rec_dll(&head, &(head->next));
```

that is changed within the function in the compound statement of the if statement.

To make it clear consider a list that contains only two nodes

```
| NULL <- 1 -> 2 | <-> | 1 <- 2 -> NULL|
```

Inside the first recursive call of the function there are executed the following statements

```
    (*a)->next = (*a)->prev;
    (*a)->prev = (*b);
```

Again pay attention to that the function is called like

```
rev_rec_dll(&head, &(head->next));
```

That is the parameter `b` of the function points to the data member `next` of the head node and the first of the above statements changes the value of the data member

```
    (*a)->next = (*a)->prev;
```

So now the expression `*b` yields data member `next` that now contains the value of the data member `prev` (in this case `NULL`).

In fact you have

```
    (*a)->next = (*a)->prev;
    (*a)->prev = ( *a )->next; //(*b);
```

because the expressions `( *a )->next` and `*b` are equivalent due to initializations of parameters by argument expressions.

That is the both data members. `next` and `prev`, get the initial value of the data member `prev` and you have

```
| NULL <- 1 -> NULL | <- | 1 <- 2 -> NULL|
```

Then the function is called like

```
rev_rec_dll(b, &((*b)->next));
```

that invokes undefined behavior because the expression `*b` yields a null pointer.

Another problem is that in this code snippet

```
else
{
    printf("reached new head\r\n");
    head = (*a);
}
```

data members `prev` and `next` of the last node in the list are not changed because the control is bypassed the compound statement of the if statement

And moreover your function will invoke undefined behavior if it will
be called for an empty list.

The function should be declared with only one parameter like for example

```
void rev_rec_dll( Node **head );
```

Here is a demonstration program that shows how the recursive function that reverses the list can be implemented.

In the demonstration program there is not used a file scope pointer to the head node. In this case within a program you will be able to define multiple lists.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

typedef struct Node
{
    uint8_t x;
    struct Node *next;
    struct Node *prev;
} Node;

void clear( Node **head )
{
    while (*head)
    {
        Node *current = *head;
        *head = ( *head )->next;
        free( current );
    }
}

size_t assign( Node **head, const uint8_t *a, size_t n )
{
    clear( head );

    size_t cnt = 0;

    for ( Node *prev = NULL; n-- && ( *head = malloc( sizeof( Node ) ) ) != NULL; cnt++)
    {
        ( *head )->x = *a++;
        ( *head )->next = NULL;
        ( *head )->prev = prev;
        prev = *head;
        head = &( *head )->next;
    }

    return cnt;
}

void rev_rec_dll( Node **head )
{
    if ( *head )
    {
        Node *tmp = ( *head )->next;
        ( *head )->next = ( *head )->prev;
        ( *head )->prev = tmp;

        if (( *head )->prev != NULL)
        {
            *head = ( *head )->prev;
            rev_rec_dll( head );
        }
    }
}

void display_nodes( const Node *head )
{
    for (; head != NULL; head = head->next)
    {
        printf( "%" PRIu8 " -> ", head->x );
    }

    puts( "null" );
}

int main( void )
{
    Node *head = NULL;
    uint8_t a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

    assign( &head, a, sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ) );

    display_nodes( head );

    rev_rec_dll( &head );

    display_nodes( head );

    clear( &head );
}
```

The program output is

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> null
6 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> null
```

Answer (score -1):

There's no real point of using pointer to a pointer in `rev_rec_dll(Node **a, Node **b)`, i would suggest you read into [practical implications of pointers to pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897366/how-do-pointer-to-pointers-work-in-c-and-when-might-you-use-them)

What you can do here is just use regular pointers like so:

```c
void rev_rec_dll(Node* a, Node* b)
{
    //check if it is last node in the list
    if(a->next != NULL)
    {
        //set next to prev and prev to next
        a->next = a->prev;
        a->prev = b;
        printf("done for node %d and moving on..\n", a->x);
        //recursive call by passing next two nodes
        rev_rec_dll(b, b->next);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("reached new head\r\n");
        head = a;
    }
}
```

then in main function call it like so

```c
rev_rec_dll(head, head->next);
```

also, as [Vlad mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75363903/12920399) you shouldn't use two parameters in this function, it adds unnecessary complexity as well as makes it a bit harder to track if you pass and use `NULL` in the future.

also also, it's best that you learn how to use debugger now to see where things hit the fan clearly.

Comment: I'd say there *is* a point to using double pointers, or at least to using a double-pointer to the source.  It is that the function can then work with any doubly-linked list, not just the particular one whose head is pointed to by file-scope variable `head`.  Also, this does not seem to address the main issue in the OP's code, which is incorrect handling of the links in the last node of the original list.