# Void ** a generic pointer?

Tags: c++, c

`void *` is a generic pointer, but what about `void **`? Is `void **` also a generic pointer?

Can we typecast `void **` to `int **`, `char **` and so on.

I would be thankful to stack overflow family for any information on this.

Comment: you can do this void **ptr; *((int *)*ptr);

Comment: @nikhilmehta no. But you can do `void *ptr; **(int**)ptr;`. As a rule of thumb, never dereference `void*`, and never cast across more than one level of pointers.

Comment: @Quentin nikhil's usage is fine, if `ptr` actually points at an initialized `void*` object: `int n = 0; void *pn = &n; void **ptr = &pn; int n2 = *((int*) *ptr);`

Comment: It is easy to see that a `void **` is not generic when you remember that it points to a *pointer* (forget about the type of pointer it points to, for a moment). It points to a pointer, and pointers have an implementation defined size and occupy memory and are formatted in a specific way.

Comment: @aschepler oops, indeed. `void*` is definitely a slippery thing.

Comment: Just adding on, the standard (both C and C++) explicitly allows pointers of different types to be different sizes:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916051/are-there-are-any-platforms-where-pointers-to-different-types-have-different-size

void* is always sufficiently large to hold all pointer types, but consider this: `int** x = new int*[10]; void** y = (void**)x;`. When you do this, while x==y, x+1!=y+1 if the sizeof(int*)!=sizeof(void*), and *x!=*y

Comment: Arjun, you mean to say (void **) could be type casted.

Comment: @IdeaHat so what about if I dont treat void** like an array?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

No. `void**` is a pointer to `void*`, and nothing else. Only `void*` acts like a generic pointer.

Note that actually trying it will probably yield consistent results, but only the above is mandated by the Standard, anything else is Undefined Behaviour and may crash without mercy.

Answer (score 8):

`void**` is a pointer to `void*`.  On top of it being undefined behavior (which while scary, the behavior is often in effect defined by your compiler), it is also a huge problem if you do the `reinterpret_cast`:

```
int x = 3;
char c = 2;
int* y = &x;
void* c_v = &c; // perfectly safe and well defined
void** z = reinterpret_cast<void**>(&y); // danger danger will robinson

*z = c_v; // note, no cast on this line
*y = 2; // undefined behavior, probably trashes the stack
```

Pointers to pointers are very different beasts than pointers.  Type changes that are relatively safe on pointers are not safe on pointers to pointers.

Comment: The `static_cast` isn't needed either.

Comment: @Yakk: Not for converting *to* `void*`; that conversion is implicit for any object pointer. A cast is needed in C++ (but not C) for converting *from* `void*` to a typed pointer.

Answer (score 7):

> Void ** a generic pointer?

`void **` is not a generic pointer. Standard says only about `void *` to be a generic pointer.

#### [Chapter 22: Pointers to Pointers](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx8.html):

> One side point about pointers to pointers and memory allocation: although the `void *` type, as returned by `malloc`, is a *generic pointer,* suitable for assigning to or from pointers of any type, the hypothetical type `void **` is not a *generic pointer to pointer.*

---

> Can we typecast `void **` to `int **`, `char **` and so on.

No. You should not.

[C-FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/ptrs/genericpp.html) says that:

> **There is no generic pointer-to-pointer type in C**. `void *` acts as a generic pointer only because conversions (if necessary) are applied automatically when other pointer types are assigned to and from `void *`'s; these conversions cannot be performed if an attempt is made to indirect upon a `void **` value which points at a pointer type other than `void *`. When you make use of a `void **` pointer value (for instance, when you use the `*` operator to access the `void *` value to which the `void **` points), **the compiler has no way of knowing whether that `void *` value was once converted from some other pointer type**. It must assume that it is nothing more than a `void *`; it cannot perform any implicit conversions.
>
> In other words, **any `void **` value you play with must be the address of an actual `void *` value somewhere; casts like `(void **)&dp`, though they may shut the compiler up, are nonportable** (and may not even do what you want; see also question 13.9). **If the pointer that the `void **` points to is not a `void *`, and if it has a different size or representation than a `void *`, then the compiler isn't going to be able to access it correctly**.

Comment: In particular, there are systems where `sizeof(char*) != sizeof(int*)`. (I.e., non-byte-addressable systems.)

Comment: @RaymondChen: do you know such systems sold today? Indeed the 1990 Cray supercomputer had `sizeof(char*) != sizeof(int*)` but I cannot name a processor or computer system sold *today* having this property.

Comment: It is not common in general purpose processors, but [according to this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3520224/902497) it can happen on DSPs.

Answer (score 1):

C implementations are free to extend the language in such a way as to allow `void**` to be used as a generic pointer-to-anything type in the presence of suitable casting operators, and in the days before the Standard implementations that could practically do so often did.  The Standard does not mandate such treatment because there are some platforms that could not efficiently accommodate such usage.  Presumably, the authors judged that requiring that programmers *who need to make their code work on such platforms* jump through hoops to work around the lack of a "pointer to any data pointer" type would be less harmful than requiring that implementations jump through hoops to accommodate such constructs without regard for whether their customers would use them.  Such judgment does not imply that the authors of the Standard intended to require that programmers jump through such hoops even when writing code that would never be called upon to run on such platforms.  Clang and gcc can be configured to support such constructs via the `-fno-strict-aliasing` option.