# Why is assignment of double ** to void ** a warning?

Tags: c, pointers

The following code works exactly as expected, but the compiler gives me incompatible pointer type warning. A cast will solve this, but I really don't understand why this should be a warning. A pointer is an integer that is an address of a certain memory area, and in my example, v has got the address of d which is an integer and that seems all. Please help me understand this issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    double *d;
    void **v;

    d = malloc(sizeof(double));
    *d = 1.1;
    printf("%.1f\n", *d);
    v = &d;
    *(double *)*v = 2.2;
    printf("%.1f\n", *d);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pointers aren't arbitrarily convertible to one another. You can only convert to and from `void *`.

Comment: `void*` is a generic pointer type. `void**` is not. There is no generic pointer-to-pointer type.

Comment: To elaborate on @KeithThompson 's comment you might find this helpful http://stackoverflow.com/q/25427587/1240985 , trying to find more. Perhaps: http://www.nongnu.org/c-prog-book/online/x658.html , I have to re-read that one.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to post this as a comment but I still don't have the reputation...  :-/

One of the few things I can think of, is Pointer Arithmetic. It wouldn't work if all types of pointers were treated the same way. So, a pointer is not just a pointer, its type does matter.

For example, try this:

```
short s = 5;
int i = 6;
printf("s: 0x%X -> 0x%X\n", &s, (&s)+1);
printf("i: 0x%X -> 0x%X\n", &i, (&i)+1);
```

The output is:

```
s: 0x270A724E -> 0x270A7250                                              
i: 0x270A7248 -> 0x270A724C
```

Note how `s` shifts **two** addresses (4E to 50, because it's a `short`), and `i` shifts **four** (48 to 4C, because it's an `int`). With `(&s)+1` we're asking to move one position of the type of the pointer.  You could use the same thing to move through an array without using `[]`.  And that's the same reason why `char *str` makes you move **one** address when you make `str++`.