# Why is there a warning for casting from char** to void**, but not from char* to void*?

Tags: c, pointers

I am quite new to C, and have been practicing with pointers. I understand that a `void *` pointer accepts a pointer of any kind, so this works fine:

```
void functionWithSingleVoidPointer(void *simplePointer)
{
    free(simplePointer);
}
int main()
{
    char *simplePointer = malloc(sizeof *simplePointer);
    functionWithSingleVoidPointer(simplePointer); //No warnings
    return 0;
}
```

However, I don't understand why this:

```
void functionWithDoubleVoidPointer(void **doublePointer)
{
    free(*doublePointer);
}
int main()
{
    char *simplePointer = malloc(sizeof *simplePointer);
    char **doublePointer = &simplePointer;
    functionWithDoubleVoidPointer(doublePointer);
}
```

gives me a warning:

> warning: passing argument 1 of ‘functionWithDoubleVoidPointer’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types] ... note: expected ‘void **’ but argument is of type ‘char **’

Why doesn't the casting from `char *` to `void *` give any warning, but the casting from `char **` to `void **` does?

Comment: Not quite related to the question but a little advice: a `type**` is a **pointer to pointer**, not a **double pointer**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25427587/void-a-generic-pointer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Void \*\* a generic pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25427587/void-a-generic-pointer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `char*` value points to a `char` object; a `void*` object can point to any kind of object. The conversion is safe (as long you don't do anything unsafe with the result).

A `char**` pointer value must point to a pointer object of type `char*` somewhere in memory. A `void**` pointer value must point to an object of type `void*`. Since `char*` and `void*` are different types, you can't just assume that you can safely treat an object of one type as if it were an object of the other type. (Most likely they have the same representation, but the language doesn't guarantee that.)

Answer (score 2):

A `void**` is not a *void pointer*, that's it.
`void**` is **a pointer to a void pointer**, which only accept void pointers.