# Is it normal to get a warning for incompatible pointer type when using void*?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm reading through The C Programming language, and I got to void pointers. The book says:

> The generic pointer type void * is used for the pointer arguments. Any pointer can be cast to void * and back again without loss of information.

And from what I can make up, it basically means that if a function has `void *` as one of it's parameters it acts as a wildcard that will accept a pointer to any kind of data type (char, float, int...).

However, when I compile this code:

```
void swap(void *v[], int a, int b)
{
    void *temp = v[a];
    v[a] = v[b];
    v[b] = temp;
}

int main()
{
    char *arr[] = {
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
        "consectetur adipiscing elit.",
        "Pellentesque consectetur",
        "massa, nec sagittis."
    };
    int SIZE = sizeof arr / sizeof *arr;
    swap(arr, 0, SIZE-1);
}
```

I'm getting the following warning:

```
j.c: In function 'main':
j.c:17:7: warning: passing argument 1 of 'swap' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]   
  swap(arr, 0, SIZE-1);
       ^~~
j.c:1:6: note: expected 'void **' but argument is of type 'char **'
 void swap(void *v[], int a, int b)
      ^~~~
```

Is this something that I should ignore? Or did I missunderstand the use of a `void` pointer?

Comment: you have to do an implicite cast to `void **`

Comment: `void *` is a generic pointer, but `void **` (same thing as `void *[]`) is not. See [Void \*\* a generic pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25427587)

Comment: @qwerty_url have you learned what pointers to pointers are yet? If not, you should probably read up on that first, otherwise, no explanation here will be able to help you.

Comment: `(void**)arr` casts `arr` to a pointer to (void pointer).

Comment: @PaulHankin So... you are basically saying: `arr` is a pointer which will point to something whose data type will be `void`? (Just want to make sure I got it right).

Comment: @qwerty_url then you may already know that in the function argument, `void *v[]` and `void **v` are the same things. Now, when you pass `arr` into the argument, it decays into a `char **`, but since (as previously mentioned) `void **` is NOT a generic pointer like `void *`, a warning is raised since they are incompatible pointer types.

Comment: No, you haven't got it right (there's at least 3 mistakes in your interpretation) - `(void**)arr` is a value of type `void**` which is a pointer to a void pointer. There's no such thing in C as "something whose data type will be void". There is a lot of material written about C already and you would be better off (and better informed) if you found a good introductory C book and read it. Here's a good list: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list