# What size will be allocated to stack and array. does array memory allocation will come under stack or it will be allocated separately

Tags: c, struct, malloc

```
int capacity =4;
struct Stack* stack =
    (struct Stack*) malloc(sizeof(struct Stack));
stack -> capacity = capacity;
stack -> top = -1;
stack -> array = (int*) malloc(stack -> capacity * sizeof(int));
```

What size will be allocated to stack and array. does array memory allocation will come under stack or it will be allocated separately.

Comment: Who teaches you to cast the result of `malloc`?

Comment: @DeiDei Probably someone that is used to use a c++ compiler to compile c code ;)

Answer (score 1):

The only definitive statement that may be made about sizes is that the memory pointed to by `stack` will be `sizeof(struct Stack)` and the memory pointed to be `stack->array` will be `4 * sizeof(int)`.   (Assuming that `malloc()` doesn't fail to allocate memory, in which case it returns `NULL`).

`sizeof(struct Stack)` is implementation defined - which means it varies between compilers, compiler settings, host systems, etc.   `sizeof(int)` is also implementation defined.

Practically, `sizeof(struct Stack)` will be *at least* the sum of sizes of its members.   A compiler may introduce additional padding between members.  The amount of padding varies between compilers.   (That's the simple explanation - the more complete explanation would go into alignment requirements for each type).

Unless all the members are of type `char`, `unsigned char`, or `signed char` (which have size `1` by definition), or arrays of those types, their size is implementation defined.

There is also no guaranteed relationships between the addresses returned by two different `malloc()` calls.  They may be "together"  (e.g. one immediately after the other in memory), but they may be completely separate.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the definition of `Stack` is like this:

```
typedef struct Stack{
    int capacity;
    int top;
    int *array;
} Stack;
```

Then the amount of allocated space for `*stack` should be `sizeof(int) /* for capacity */ + sizeof(int) /* for top */ + *X* /* for *array */` (i.e- the sum of all the members' sizes of the struct).

On the other hand, amount of allocated space for `array` will be `capacity*sizeof(int)`.

The allocations of `*stack` and `*array` are done independently in your case - because when you are making allocation for `*stack`, you are not constructing any array - you are just allocating for a pointer (along with other `struct` members) - which can not only be used to create an array, but can also be used to point a single `int` variable. After that allocation, you made an allocation for an array using the pointer you just created. The later allocation (`*array`) might be made adjacent to your previous allocation (`*stack`) - but it depends on the OS.

`*X*` : The size of a pointer depends on the architecture of you PC (i.e- your processor, RAM capacity, OS version (Win/Linux/Mac,x86/x64)), compiler options, as well as what type of pointer it is (i.e- is it an `int` pointer, or a `double` pointer). (Reference [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3520059/5456631),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/916051/5456631),[3](https://www.quora.com/What-is-size-of-a-pointer-in-C); and [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1474076/5456631))