# Are pointers of the same size?

Tags: c, pointers

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Are there are any platforms where pointers to different types have different sizes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916051/are-there-are-any-platforms-where-pointers-to-different-types-have-different-size)
>   [are all data pointers of the same size in one platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241205/are-all-data-pointers-of-the-same-size-in-one-platform)

`sizeof(Bucket *)` is the same as `sizeof(int *)`,right?

BTW,is `char arr[];` valid in c90?

Comment: Dup of [Are there are any platforms where pointers to different types have different sizes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916051/are-there-are-any-platforms-where-pointers-to-different-types-have-different-size), [Can the Size of Pointers Vary Depending on what's Pointed To?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473935/can-the-size-of-pointers-vary-depending-on-whats-pointed-to)

Comment: you should split this into two questions so that they can be well answered separately

Comment: Duplicate of [are all data pointers of the same size in one platform?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241205/are-all-data-pointers-of-the-same-size-in-one-platform)

Answer (score 4):

I believe there is no requirement that pointers are all the same size. The only requirement is that all object pointers can be stored in `void *`, that when cast to `void *` and back they'll be the same, and that all function pointers, if cast to another type of function pointer and back again, will be the same. (Casting function pointers to `void *` is not guaranteed to work. Sorry if I indicated otherwise.)

In practice, I think the only time you'll find pointers of different sizes is if you care about C++'s member-function pointers, or you work on a more obscure architecture.

In C90, `char arr[];` is a valid way to pre-declare a global array of to-be-determined length. Note that `char arr[]` is an incomplete type, so you have to declare it before you can use `sizeof`. It's not valid the way it is in C99, to make flexible array members.

Comment: -1 Again, incorrect.  See http://c-faq.com/ptrs/generic.html

Comment: I think -1 for an unclear wording is a bit harsh. I honestly forgot all about function pointers until the second paragraph of my answer, so I didn't think to make the distinction earlier, especially since the OP didn't seem particularly interested in function pointers.

Comment: Is `char arr[];` valid in c89?

Comment: @arr - As valid as it is in C90. C89 == C90 in pretty much all respects.

Comment: Can you elaborate more about []?what do you mean by "you have to declare it before you can use sizeof."?

Comment: @arr - `char arr[]; int main(void) { printf("%s\n", arr); return 0; } char arr[] = "Hello, world!";` is valid. We can use `arr` even though it isn't defiend, but it is an incomplete type, so it would be invalid to take the `sizeof(arr)` until after we define it (with `char arr[] = "Hello, world!";`). Basically, `char arr[]` isn't tremendously useful in C89/C90, and in C99 is only useful for flexible array members (which you can do with some work in C89/C90 anyway).

Comment: Are you sure this is valid? I would agree if you make it `extern char arr[];` but `char arr[];` is a definition and not merely a declaration, and thus I don't think it's valid to leave the `[]` empty.

Comment: @R.. - I believe it is. At least, it works when I compile it with `gcc -ansi -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror`. I forget where exactly I read that it worked (probably on SO somewhere).

Answer (score 2):

Original post:

> Yes, that's right. Pointers are of the
>   same size.

But, that's wrong. I've shot too fast! I'm sorry for that. Some "cases" of different pointer sizes do exist, platform dependent and also type dependent: Have a look at http://c-faq.com/ptrs/generic.html and http://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html for examples or at least general explanations. (Many thanks @fmark and @paxdiablo, I've also learned something). However, I never ever had a situation where pointers were not the same size (fortunately/unfortunately?).

Comment: BTW,is char arr[]; valid in c90?

Comment: That is correct but the size of the pointer is platform dependent

Comment: Really?  Would you like to cite your source for that claim ("pointers are of the same size")? As in: which bit of the ISO standard mandates this?

Comment: In practice this is true, but some peripheral searching suggests that it's not necessarily the case.

Comment: -1, Incorrect.  See http://c-faq.com/ptrs/generic.html

Comment: @pax: No, but could you give an example for the case pointers are not the same size? Of course, the concrete size of pointers is platform dependent, as drow already said. But, then, sizeof(T*) is always equal to sizeof(U*) for any T and U. If not, please provide an example. I'd be pretty interested in it.

Comment: http://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html - I didn't downvote you, BTW, I wanted to give you a chance to rectify it, especially since most of those architectures are dinosaurs (though DOS is still in use a little).