# POSIX restrictions on pointer types in C

Tags: c, posix, function-pointers, dlsym

### Background

The [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/nframe.html) adds a lot of library functions and other identifiers to the C language. In the description of the [`dlsym()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dlsym.html) function, it says (with my emphasis):

> #### SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
> #include <dlfcn.h>
>
> void *dlsym(void *restrict handle, const char *restrict name);
> ```
>
> #### DESCRIPTION
>
> The *dlsym*() function shall obtain the address of a symbol
>   (a **function identifier** or a data object identifier)
>   ...

The C standard doesn't guarantee that a function pointer can be converted to a `void *`, or even that the size of the pointers are the same. This effectively adds an additional restriction on C's type system.

### Question

My question is this:

- Is there a *normative* reference for this restriction of C's type system, or is it only deducible from the description of certain library functions?

  Is POSIX even implementable on a system where `sizeof (function pointer) > sizeof (void *)`?

### References

- The C11 Standard (final public draft): [**n1570**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)
- The POSIX Standard from [The Open Group](http://opengroup.org/): [**POSIX.1-2008**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/nframe.html)
- The POSIX [**`dlsym()` function**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dlsym.html)

Comment: Can you site an example of a ***system***  _where sizeof (function pointer) > sizeof (void *)?_

Comment: @ryyker: No. I have heard rumours about such systems, at least in the past, but I don't know of any myself. It is mostly a theoretical question for my part.

Comment: @ryyker A compiler for MS-DOS in the medium data model regime would be such an *implementation*.

Comment: The [POSIX `<stdarg.h>` documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/stdarg.h.html#tag_13_45) says about exceptions where type mismatch between passed argument and how it is fetched via `va_arg` is not undefined as an XSI extension: _Both types are pointers._ Might help somewhat, though it doesn't give a satisfying answer.

Comment: @ryyker i used to work on MSP430, which is a 16-bit system. its c compiler from IAR implements function pointers with 32-bit length, while `void *` is 16-bit. the reason to have such an implementation is code can reside not only in ram, but in flash too.

Comment: @ryyker : pmg can http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473935/can-the-size-of-pointers-vary-depending-on-whats-pointed-to

Answer (score 7):

The [dlsym() reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dlsym.html) says the conversion is not defined by the C standard but that a conforming implementation has to make this work correctly. So on systems where this can not be made to work would not be a conforming implementation and would presumably document this:

> Note that conversion from a void * pointer to a function pointer as
>   in:
>
> ```
> fptr = (int (*)(int))dlsym(handle, "my_function");
> ```
>
> is not defined by the ISO C standard. This standard requires this
>   conversion to work correctly on conforming implementations.

there is an old article that talks about this from the [C++ perspective](https://web.archive.org/web/20061214100447/http://www.trilithium.com/johan/2004/12/problem-with-dlsym/) and links to an older version of the [dlsym() reference](http://www.trilithium.com/johan/2004/12/problem-with-dlsym/) and has a more detailed explanation:

> The ISO C standard does not require that pointers to functions can be cast back and forth to pointers to data. Indeed, the ISO C standard
>   does not require that an object of type void * can hold a pointer to a
>   function. Implementations supporting the XSI extension, however, do
>   require that an object of type void * can hold a pointer to a
>   function. The result of converting a pointer to a function into a
>   pointer to another data type (except void *) is still undefined,
>   however. Note that compilers conforming to the ISO C standard are
>   required to generate a warning if a conversion from a void * pointer
>   to a function pointer is attempted as in:
>
> ```
> fptr = (int (*)(int))dlsym(handle, "my_function");
> ```
>
> Due to the problem noted here, a future version may either add a new
>   function to return function pointers, or the current interface may be
>   deprecated in favor of two new functions: one that returns data
>   pointers and the other that returns function pointers.

Comment: "required to generate a warning". This is not true as the C standard does not have a concept of warning.

Comment: @n.m. well that was a a quote from the 2004 version of the reference and that language has been removed from the more recent version. I am assuming it was an editorial issue and what was really meant was diagnostic.

Comment: Perhaps a simpler solution would be make `dlsym` return an `intptr_t` (and require that `intptr_t` is able to represent function pointer types).