# Why doesn't this C++ code give compilation error?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, structure

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct a{
    int e;
    struct abc *d;
};

struct abc{
    int c;
};

int main()
{
 return 0;  
}
```

I have defined the `struct abc` after definition of `struct a` in which i have declared a structure pointer for `abc`. This is supposed to throw compilation error because `abc` is used before its declaration. But, it doesn't, why?
Whereas when i replace it with just `struct abc d` instead of `struct abc *d`, it is giving compilation error as expected.

Comment: Having a pointer to an unknown data-type needs no extra information.- A pointer is a pointer. On the other hand, having an instance of an unknown data-type cannot be resolved, since you need to know the size of the structure to allocate space for it.

Comment: No, it's not used. The compiler knows the size of a *pointer* to a struct, because those pointers are always of the same size.

Comment: poorly researched question.

Comment: @BoPersson but there are architectures that `sizeof(char*) != sizeof(int*)` [Can the size of pointers vary between data and function pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1473935/995714) [Are there are any platforms where pointers to different types have different sizes?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1539196/995714) how can the compiler knows the pointer size in those cases?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc - True, but pointers to structs and classes are required to all have the same size on a given system.

Comment: @BoPersson: The entire purpose of the question is "how does the compiler know `abc` _is_ a class" (C++ does not have struct[ure]s)

Comment: @alain: Note that the question in the post body _is_ the question, not "a follow-up question". You cannot reasonably suggest that the entire primary question is whatever is written in the post title and nothing else, and that any text in the post body is just an addendum. The title is only there to summarise and identify the question; nothing more.

Answer (score 6):

This declaration

```
struct abc *d;
```

on the one hand declares `struct abc` and on the other hand declares pointer `d` of type `struct abc *`.

In this declaration there is no need to have the exact definition of struct abc because no data member of the structure is used.

This specifier `struct abc` is called elaborated type specifier.

It introduces a new type in the given scope or refers to an already declared type.

Answer (score 5):

You're right in that, usually, you'd need a forward declaration of such a type:

```
// Forward declaration
struct bar;

struct foo
{
    bar* d;   // only a pointer-to-bar; forward declaration sufficient
};

struct bar
{
    int c;
};
```

However, you are (for some reason) using the antiquated idiom of writing `struct` before the type name. (This was required in C but has never been in C++.)

```
struct foo
{
    struct bar* d;
};

struct bar
{
    int c;
};
```

Because you write `struct bar` there instead of just `bar`, *that itself counts as a forward declaration* of sorts. The compiler now knows that `bar` is a type and that's all it needs to know.

It's a bit obscure and subtle, but that's why you do not need the prior forward declaration any more.

> `[C++11: 3.1/4]:` *[ Note:* **A class name can also be implicitly declared by an *elaborated-type-specifier*** (7.1.6.3). *—end note ]*
>
> `[C++11: 3.3.2/6]:` **The point of declaration of a class first declared in an *elaborated-type-specifier* is as follows**:
>
> - for a declaration of the form
>
>   *class-key attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> identifier* `;`
>
>   the *identifier* is declared to be a *class-name* in the scope that contains the declaration, otherwise
> - **for an *elaborated-type-specifier* of the form**
>
>   ***class-key identifier***
>
>   if the *elaborated-type-specifier* is used in the *decl-specifier-seq* or *parameter-declaration-clause* of a function defined in namespace scope, the *identifier* is declared as a *class-name* in the namespace that contains the declaration; otherwise, except as a friend declaration, **the *identifier* is declared in the smallest namespace or block scope that contains the declaration**. *[ Note:* These rules also apply within templates. *—end note ] [ Note:* Other forms of *elaborated-type-specifier* do not declare a new name,
>     and therefore must refer to an existing *type-name*. See 3.4.4 and 7.1.6.3. *—end note ]*
>
> `[C++11: 3.4.4/2]:` *[..]* **If the *elaborated-type-specifier* is introduced by the class-key and this lookup does not find a previously declared *type-name***, or if the *elaborated-type-specifier* appears in a declaration with the form:
>
> *class-key attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> identifier* `;`
>
> **the *elaborated-type-specifier* is a declaration that introduces the *class-name* as described in 3.3.2**.

Answer (score 2):

It works, because the compiler has all the information it needs:

- the size of `d` (= size of pointer)<sup>1</sup>, and
- what `abc` is (it's a `struct`).

---

If you stored an *object* of type `struct abc` instead:

```
struct abc d;
```

it would result in an error because the information about the size and memory layout of `d` is missing (because `struct abc` hasn't been defined yet).

Also if you left out the `struct` keyword:

```
abc *d;
```

then the information about what `abc` is would be missing, and it would be an error as well.

---

> This is supposed to throw compilation error because `abc` is used before its declaration.

It is not *used*, it is only *declared*. Using `abc` via a pointer would require *dereferencing* the pointer first (and if `abc` is not defined at that point, it would be an error).

---

<sup>1</sup> Pointers to incomplete types are allowed because the size and memory layout of a pointer doesn't depend on what it points to.

Answer (score 0):

Pointer declared to incomplete types are allowed .

This is forward declaration-

> Forward declaration is a declaration preceeding an actual definition, usually for the purpose of being able to reference the declared type when the definition is not available. Of course, not everything may be done with the declared-not-defined structure, but in certain context it is possible to use it. Such type is called incomplete.

A declaration of the following form

```
  class-key attr identifier ;   // struct abc *d; (Your case)
```

Declares a class type which will be defined later in this scope. Until the definition appears, this class name has incomplete type.

When `struct a` is declared it doesn't know the specs of `struct abc` yet, but you can forward reference it.

Comment: You did not explain _how_ this is a forward declaration. It's a subtle one that the OP doesn't understand, which is the basis of the question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  Well ,see it now.

Comment: I already did.​ "Declaring pointer to struct" is not responsible for this behaviour. Naming the type as `struct abc` rather than just `abc` is. This has been well-covered in other answers.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Did it now address the problem yet ?

Answer (score -2):

In `struct a` you refer to a *pointer* to `struct abc`, so the compiler has no need for more information about it to compute the size  of the `d` member.

In a later stage, it will check that `struct abc` is defined, if needed (for exemple if it is dereferenced). This explains the rationale for the standard which

- forbids to declare variables of *unknown type* (`abc`, when not forwarded, is such an unknown type)
- allows to declare them as pointers to *incomplete type*. (`struct abc` is an incomplete type: at least it is known to be some `struct`).

Practically, declaring a structure as

```
 struct a {
    struct abc *d;
 }
```

amounts to forwarding the declaration of (struct) type `abc`, as in

```
struct abc;           // forward
struct a {
   abc *d;            // legal
};
```

However the type `abc` is incomplete, so the following is illegal

```
struct z {
   struct abc y;   // error : incomplete struct type
}
```

For the curiosity, this is OK:

```
struct A {
   struct B* ptr1;    // forwards declaration of B, and use it
   B* ptr2;           // B is a known (incomplete-)type name now
}
```

Comment: This is not the reason.

Comment: The reason is, it has no reason to show an error, because there is no error

Comment: OP already stated that. You were supposed to explain *why* there is no error.

Comment: There is no error because the code perfectly conforms to the rules of the language, and the compiler does its job properly. I see no point for discussion here.
What can be explained is the rationale behind the standard of the language.  A dull definition af the struct is not required, because is is not needed for a member which is "only" a pointer.

Comment: You need to explain, why `struct a { int e; abc* d; };` does not compile, although it meets your proposed (fantasy) rule set.

Comment: So your answer to "why is there no error reported?" is "because there is no error"? Wow, helpful.

Comment: _"A dull[sic] definition af[sic] the struct is not required, because is[sic] is not needed for a member which is 'only' a pointer."_ No, but a forward declaration _is_, and the OP is asking why it [seemingly] wasn't in this case.

Comment: Surroy about the typos : most of you have probably  read "a full definition", and "it is not needed"
"Full definition" means, precisely, "not a forward declaration". 
This is callled "incomplete type" in the standard, whiche states (3.9.2) « Pointers
to incomplete types are allowed although there are restrictions on what can be done with them ». And no forward is required.

Comment: You are still missing the vital detail: Why is `struct abc*` and incomplete type, and `abc*` isn't? It's a reincarnation of my previous suggestion to explain, why `struct a { int e; abc* d; };` does **not** compile, even though it meets all your made-up requirements.

Comment: I'm afraid you're confusing "*incomplete type*" and "*unknown type name*'.
 **incomplete type** is a notion defined by the standard.  See for example   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/200xfxh6.aspx <<  An "incomplete type" can be:
-    A structure type whose members you have not yet specified.
-    A union type whose members you have not yet specified.
-    An array type whose dimension you have not yet specified.
>> .
In "`abc*`", the name `abc` is an **unknown type name**. That's a different story.
And it is ok to use a pointer to an inccomplete type

Comment: I'm afraid, you are confusing what you did write, and what you meant to write. Read your answer again. It explains, why `struct a { int e; abc* d; };` should compile, even though it doesn't. Unless your answer includes the information, that `struct abc*` is a pointer to an incomplete type, whereas `abc*` is a pointer to an unknown type, it doesn't address the question. Four downvotes seem to agree with this.

Comment: Maybe my answer didn't made clear enough that the type was "pointer to struct with unknown name", not the more general "pointer to unknown type" ?  And, second point,  `struct abc *d` actually contains a forward declaration of `abc` as a struct type. 
So the OP assertion "abc is used before declaration" is somehow incorrect.

Comment: The OP was **asking** a question. Your answer should address inaccuracies or wrong assumptions. It still doesn't, and you sill left out the most interesting piece of information: Contrasting `struct a { struct b* c; };` with `struct a { b* c; };`. You have been told, time upon time. I give up, sorry, I cannot remove the downvote.