# What are the parameters on which size of a function pointer depends?

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

I just wanted to know the various reasons that might affect the size of a function pointer from memory perspective.

I'd like to emphasize that my question isn't about how functions pointers could be used and how they could be type-cast. It's just about if I declare a function pointer like

```
 int (*fptr)(int, int);
```

and create a variable of it

```
fptr fun1;
```

what is the size I'm expected to get if I run it on a 32/64 bit machine?

Is it possible to determine the size of a function pointer simply by looking at its declaration, like I could tell a void pointer would size 4 bytes on a 32-bit machine.

Comment: Maybe you should emphasize the problem you are actually having and trying to solve? Please read about [the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: only depends on target CPU architecture - 32 or 64 bits (on some older systems it was 20, 16)

Comment: it's the same like your void pointer - 32 or 64 bits depending on for what system your are compiling - can be determined at compile time. There are pre-defined compiler `#define`s for it. What compiler are you using?

Comment: Are you familiar with `sizeof` or perhaps `PTRDIFF_MAX`?

Comment: Related: [What is guaranteed about the size of a function pointer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941793/what-is-guaranteed-about-the-size-of-a-function-pointer).

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473935/can-the-size-of-pointers-vary-between-data-and-function-pointers and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916051/are-there-any-platforms-where-pointers-to-different-types-have-different-sizes

Comment: Why do you need to know this?

Comment: @mvidelgauz gcc could you please provide any refernce to support your answer.

Comment: If you work in IBM iSeries machines, I believe you'll find that function pointers are 128-bit values, even though data pointers are 64-bit values.  Odd modes for Intel 80286 can have different sizes for data and function pointers in some modes (small data, large code; or large data, small code; etc.)

Comment: @2501 What has it got to do with the question asked? sizeof can specify the size of function pointer after I run the code. Is it possible to tell the size without running the code?

Comment: @Martin R I've already read the link and the question I've asked is different

Comment: @rango: you can look at the compiler manual — or you can run code that evaluates `sizeof(void (*)(void))` or similar.  Main two choices.  The other one is hear-say from the programmers working on the machine too, but they're apt to have slightly blinkered perspectives.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Do you mean to say that they are always fixed for a fixed architecture type irrespective of the arguments or return type passed?

Comment: It's a reasonable inference.  A pointer to function can be converted from one type to another type and then back again without loss of information.  ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §6.2.3.2 ¶8 _A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a function of another
type and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer. If a converted
pointer is used to call a function whose type is not compatible with the referenced type,
the behavior is undefined._

Answer (score 2):

Rango, look [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html#Common-Predefined-Macros):

```
__SIZEOF_POINTER__ // Pre-defined GCC macro
```

and for MS Visual C/C++ compiler you can check macro `_WIN64`, `_M_IX86` and others that indicate target processor architecture. Full list [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx).

P.S. After some thinking I have to admit that my statement that function pointer will have the same size as `void*` was wrong (I can imagine architectures where memory for data and for code may be addressed differently). Anyway, as for the question *"Is it possible to determine the size of a function pointer"* and taking into account clarification I got in the comment that OP works with gcc, `__SIZEOF_POINTER__` may serve as an answer. Although answer provided by @2501 in their comment is much better - `sizezeof(fptr)` should work with any compiler

Comment: That's called a 'link-only' answer and isn't popular.  And `__SIZEOF_POINTER__` is a GCC-specific feature; it is not a general feature of standard C.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I changed to line of code and link

Comment: Agreed — you changed it.  You didn't explain what it does, what it's for, or what its limitations are.  (And, JFTR, not my down-vote — yet, at any rate.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Please read comment, OP asked for GCC

Comment: The question doesn't mention GCC.  If the OP commented about GCC (not seen it yet, but I assume it is there), then the OP needs to update the question to say so (tag and content).

Comment: @mvidelgauz http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941793/what-is-guaranteed-about-the-size-of-a-function-pointer The top answer states that "no guarantee that a void * can hold a function pointer. "

Comment: JFTR I don't care about down-votes, I think OP got their answer - that what is important

Comment: @mvidelgauz I stated that I used gcc. I didn't intend this question to be gcc specific. Apologies if it meant to you that way.

Comment: @rango you asked about **size of pointer**, where does my answer imply that void* can hold function pointer?

Comment: @mvidelgauz Even if you meant to imply that __SIZE_OF_POINTER__ is equal to number of bytes of void *, its gcc specific. For other compilers it's not always true. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473935/can-the-size-of-pointers-vary-between-data-and-function-pointers

Answer (score 1):

In any one program, all function pointers in C have the same size.  A function pointer need not have the same size as `void *` according to the C standard.  For that reason, you can't portably assign a function pointer to `void *`.  However, Posix in effect does require that the two have the same size, else `dlopen(2)` wouldn't work.

> what is the size I'm expected to get

That depends on what you expect?  Pointer size -- data or function -- is up to the compiler (and its options).  If you're programming on a popular, general-purpose platform, likely pointer size will be `sizeof(size_t)`.  But if you're doing something specialized, the only safe answer is RTFM.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer has only one size.  It does not matter what it points to.  It is large enough to hold the address of a location in the process's virtual memory that can be accessed.  This is typically 64 bits (8 bytes) on current CPUs and 32 bits on older ones.

Comment: *A pointer has only one size.* [No.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916051/are-there-any-platforms-where-pointers-to-different-types-have-different-sizes)

Comment: @Bruce Please read the following post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473935/can-the-size-of-pointers-vary-between-data-and-function-pointers