# How are pointer variables allocated in memory? Does the memory allocation depend on datatype?

Tags: c, pointers

```
void main
{ 
 int a,*b;

 a=10;

 a=&b;

 printf("value of a %d",a);

 printf("value of b %d",b);

}
```

How are pointer variables allocated in memory? Does the memory allocation depend on datatype?

Comment: By the way, `printf("%d", b)` is undefined behavior. It will probably print something sensible if `int` and `int*` just so happen to have the same size, but that's not guaranteed and you should use the correct format for what you're printing. In this case, `printf("%p", (void*)b)`.

Comment: @Steve: also, even if they have the same size, pointers may be passed in registers and ints through the stack, and the result will not be sensible anyway :)

Comment: @pmg: Agreed. But *probably* varargs are all passed on the stack and hence *probably* something sensible. Passing the first few varargs (of certain types) in registers, until you run out of registers and have to pass the rest on the stack anyway, is a fantastic idea right up to the point where you have to implement `va_copy`, and code inside varargs functions where you want to use registers but haven't haven't read the varargs yet, and you realise that it's going to be effort :-)

Comment: Ah, getting less *probable* by the month, then, as more people move to 64bit. Not that `int` and `int*` are the same size there anyway, so at least you'd expect nonsense even in the best possible case.

Answer (score 4):

They are allocated in the same way that (for example) integers are. And the type of the thing they point to has no effect on that.

Answer (score 2):

This particular pointer is allocated on the stack, because it is an automatic variable. This is no different from an "ordinary", non-pointer variable. If by "the memory allocation" you mean the *size* of the allocation, then yes, the size of a pointer [may depend on the pointee type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916051/are-there-are-any-platforms-where-pointers-to-different-types-have-different-size).

You can find out the size of a pointer with `sizeof`. In this case, `b` takes up `sizeof(int *)` bytes, which is platform-dependent (typically 4 or 8 bytes on modern machines).

You could allocate a pointer on the freestore (heap) if you wanted:

```
int **pp = malloc(sizeof(int *));  // allocates space for a single pointer
```

(Note, btw., that your example program is erroneous: `a=&b` should be `b=&a`.)

Answer (score 0):

Automatic allocation ends up on the [stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation). Dynamic allocation ends up on the [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_memory_allocation). No matter what data type it is.

Comment: static allocation ends up in the static region. You're confusing static and automatic.

Answer (score -1):

pointer is itself a variable which points to other variable. It always contain the address of whatever it is pointing to. As address is of same size, all pointers have same size, no matter what they point to.