# Get size of pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, sizeof

How do I get the size of a pointer in C using `sizeof`? I want to malloc some memory to store a pointer (not the value being pointed to).

Comment: AFAIK, pointer to different types are not guaranteed to have the same size.

Comment: Really? Can you provide an example/source? I've always assumed all pointers have the same size because they're all referring to memory locations within the same address space.

Comment: @Matt: A trivial counterexample is a function pointer; that's not necessarily the same address space.  See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916051/are-there-are-any-platforms-where-pointers-to-different-types-have-different-siz.

Comment: Standard C mandates that pointers to objects are all the same size, but does not mandate that pointers to functions are the same size as pointers to objects (remember 80286 and small, medium, large, huge memory models, etc).  POSIX mandates that pointers to functions are the same size as pointers to objects.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Do you have a specific standard quote in mind for "pointers to objects are all the same size"?

Comment: @Oli: Generally, §6.3.2.3 Pointers in ISO/IEC 9899:1999 (the C99 standard).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I guess clause 7 is the closest, but I'm not sure it mandates anything (because of the "if not correctly aligned -> UB" caveat).  Theoretically, a `T *` could be `log2(sizeof(T))` bits smaller than a `char *`, yet still be compliant.

Comment: Might be a little late to comment, but `char *` on machines that aren't byte-addressable are generally bigger than say `int *` on these machines. This is due to the fact you need to store both the address of the word you're addressing, as well as the offset to the specific character you want, whereas for an integer you only need to store the address of the word. Of course, every computer I've ever touched has been byte-addressable...

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Given an arbitrary type (I've chosen `char` here, but that is for sake of concrete example):

```
char *p;
```

You can use either of these expressions:

```
sizeof(p)
sizeof(char *)
```

Leading to a `malloc()` call such as:

```
char **ppc = malloc(sizeof(char *));
char **ppc = malloc(sizeof(p));
char **ppc = malloc(sizeof(*ppc));
```

The last version has some benefits in that if the type of `ppc` changes, the expression still allocates the correct space.

Comment: Parentheses optional in the first expression.

Comment: @CarlNorum True, but I find they clarify the expression quite a bit. That's a matter of style, and not something that should be edited.

Comment: The parentheses on `sizeof()` are optional in some cases.  In the 25+ years of C programming that I've done, I've never bothered to expend the effort to remember when the parentheses are optional and when they're not; they're always correct, so I simply decline to learn when they're optional.  Consistency is more valuable to me.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: No: it is a matter of different syntax; it is either `sizeof expression` or `sizeof (type)`. In the former case, extra parenthesis are ignored (because of `expr := (expr)`) But the parenthesis are just as superfluous as with *for instance* `return (expression);`

Comment: @Kaz: which is the unnecessary syntax?  Remembering 'sizeof(something)` with parentheses is always correct is a whole heap easier than remembering when the parentheses are not required.  I regard the missing parentheses as one of the pitfalls that C compiler writers have to deal with, and ordinary mortal programmers should never have to worry about.

Comment: I like omitting the parentheses to make it clear that I'm evaluating the size of an lvalue instead of a type.

Comment: I think if you're working with C, it's best to memorize as much as you can. The grammar is not very large; there is not a lot. C has different kinds of parentheses. The parentheses in `sizeof (void *)` are not the same as those in `sizeof x`, and those are not the same as those in `while (expr)`. There is no excuse for not knowing the syntax of thy programming language; repent and be forgiven, amen.  Sizeof takes an argument with no parentheses, but a type name requires them; it's a kind of lopped-off cast expression. You could do `sizeof (void *) 0`; but you can chop the zero.

Comment: @Kaz: we're going to have to agree to disagree. There are no circumstances I can think of where `sizeof (void *) 0` is syntactically valid. You can use `sizeof(void *)` or `sizeof((void *)0)` but not what you wrote. Maybe you were intending that to be a way of thinking about it; I don't see it helping me, or (much more to the point) helping beginners. I regard this conversation as closed. There are the two schools of thought, exemplified by upvotes on comments to this question. The two have yet to meet common ground in my experience; I've had heated discussions on the topic before to no avail.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler re: your last sentence "The last version has some benefits in that if the type of ppc changes, the expression still allocates the correct space" -- isn't the size of a pointer itself dependent only on the architecture compiled for rather than the pointed-to type?

Comment: @CCJ: When the type of the variable is a pointer to pointer, yes.  If it is changed to `struct CharPointerContainer *ppc = malloc(sizeof(*ppc));` the `malloc()` still allocates the correct size, regardless of whether there are other members in the structure than just a `char *` or not.

Answer (score 16):

This should do the trick:

```
sizeof(void*)
```

Comment: Can you please give a short example using this with a short program in C?

Comment: @Bixo: `int main() { return sizeof(void*); }`.

Answer (score 2):

```
char *ptr;
char **ptr2 = malloc(sizeof(ptr));
```

should be able to achieve your purpose. No matter what the platform is, this code should work.