# Casting pointers?

Tags: c, memory, embedded

What will happen If we cast 32 bit pointer to 8 bit?

I assume that for example we have 0x8000 0000 and if we cast to 8 bit, the value of the new pointer will be 0x00. Am I right?

Comment: It's implementation-dependent, I think.

Comment: what is `8 bit` pointer? or did you mean pointer to `8 bit` data type?

Comment: I think byte data type.

Comment: A pointer is a pointer, the size depend on platform. If you cast the pointer the pointed value size change.

Comment: Is it possible to cast pointers so they're a different/smaller size? Even it is, it seems redundant - shouldn't pointers be able to point to every memory address?

Comment: Are all addresses in RAM 32bit wide?

Comment: @Lazar I had assumed that depending on whether it was 32 / 64 bit memory, it would be the same but I could be wrong.   Time to research!

Comment: No, the width of memory addresses and hence the size of a pointer variable depend on the CPU architecture you're compiling for. Specifically, it roughly depends on the max. amount of RAM+ROM a CPU can handle.

Comment: So question is if I write this &variableName Whether I get 32bit value as pointer to that variable in RAM?

Comment: On a 32-bit CPU that's probably what you'll get. Check out `sizeof( somePtr )` when compiling for your target.

Comment: So its 32bit ARM processor, and I assume that all addresses I get from &somevariablename are 32bit, no matter if variable is in RAM or ROM

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760113/get-size-of-pointer-in-c

Comment: Possibly related too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916051/are-there-are-any-platforms-where-pointers-to-different-types-have-different-siz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pointer is a pointer, depend on platform. On a 32 bits CPU a pointer is always 32 bits.

```
void *temp = 0x8000000;
uint8_t *temp = 0x8000000;
uint16_t *temp = 0x8000000;
```

If you cast the pointer you change the pointed value size.

```
void *temp = 0x80000000;
uint8_t temp2 = *((char *)(temp)); // return a single char (8 bits) at 0x80000000
uint16_t temp3 = *((short *)(temp)); // return a single short (16 bits) at 0x80000000
```

Comment: I'm using 32bit ARM Cortex-M3 processor. I'm just getting confused that if cast 32bit pointer to 8bit, we'll read from the wrong address, because 0x8000 0000 and 0x00 points to different memory locations, ofc depends on memory mapping.

Comment: @Lazar, pointer to 8-bit value is still 32/64-bit, and you can confirm this easily by inspecting sizeof. Ie. sizeof(int *), sizeof(uint8_t *) etc. The size of pointer target has nothing to do with the pointer size.

Comment: @domen So for example (uint8_t*)data represents an 32bit pointer to 8bit value?

Comment: @Lazar, correct (mostly, but it could be 64-bit or maybe something else even).

Comment: As I wrote, is platform dependent. In case of 64 bit paltform the pointer will be 64 bits wide. In your case, Cortex-M3, is 32 bits.

Answer (score 0):

On a x86 arch CPU a pointer is just a integer pointing to a memory area.
What you are really asking, i think, and hope, is if is possible to have a pointer to an integer, and then cast it to pointer to a char.

You can look inside the bits of an integer by creating a pointer to it and cast it to a narrower type, such as char and then increment it.

Basically, if you would increment a char pointer, you will move up only one byte inside the integer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are actually architectures which have different pointers of different size. A classical x86 would be to have near and far pointers. The former had 16 bits and was restricted to a certain memory area. Any usage outside this area would have been undefined. The far pointer consisted of two 16 bit values (segment:offset) in a singel 32 bit variable. The segment part spcified the memory region the pointer was valid for, while the offset was actually identical to a near pointer.

However, that was (and is) not part of the C standard, but architecture-specific extensions. As these might have been accepted as crucial for the platform, it was supported by all toolchains available, but still nothing standard.

For your pointers, you should - in general - never fiddle with a pointer, expecially never cast it to a type which cannot hold all bits required for the pointer. If you have to store a pointer in an integer variable for some reason, use `uintptr_t` or `intptr_t` which are defined in `stdint.h` as of C99 standard. However, they are optional, so your toolchain might not support them (gcc for instances does; not idea if Microsoft already had the time to add this header to VS).

Remember that the value stored in `uintptr_t` (for example) might not be the same as a direct cast to another integer type (but for ARM this is the case as I know myself).

If you are asking, however, how to compress a pointer value, you might first cast it to `unitptr_t` and then compress the integer value using one of the well-known algorithms (Huffman, etc.).