# struct casting ansi c 89

Tags: c, casting, struct, c89

Are struct well defined in strict c 89?
I mean this code

```
struct a {
    int a, b;
    void * c;
} k;
//init k...
struct b {
    int u, w;
    long *data;
} p = *(struct b*)&k;
```

is going to work on every compiler that support the standard? If I reverse the cast (e.g. cast from struct b to struct a) c is going to be the same as the beginning?
I'm pretty sure it works with gcc(even with -ansi -pedantic), microsoft compiler and so on, but does it guarantee that it is standard c 89?

Thank you!

Comment: Sanity aside, there is no assurance that the `void*` value in `k.c` is an address properly aligned to hold an implementation-supported `long` value. Which is to say, unless the address in `k.c` is from a known-validly-aligned address-of-long (or something more strict on the implementation), you run the risk of a bus-error on dereference of `p.data`.

Comment: yeah, I know that k.c is a valid address of long, ad that I'm going to convert just from long* to void* and viceversa!

Comment: @WhozCraig: Even beyond is issue of alignment, is there any guarantee that the bit representation of a `void*` and a `sizeof(long*)` will match (or even be the same size)?  Not all machines support hardware byte addressing; on some DSPs, for example, a pointer is 16 bits and points to a 16-bit word of memory.  The compiler I used for one of those implemented `char` and `int` as 16 bits, but unless later standards have changed, it could legally have had `char` be 8 bits, `sizeof(int*)` be 2 (one 16-bit word) and `sizeof(void*)` be 4 (two 16-bit words).  That would have significantly...

Comment: ...slowed down operations with `char*` types (good reason for the compiler not to do that) but I think some later DSPs in that family added some instructions to load or store a char accessed as base[index], where `base` is a word address and `index` is a byte offset; if compilers for those DSPs offer an 8-bit `char` option, the logical size for `char*` would be two 16-bit words while `int*` would be one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do this. Copy the fields manually:

```
struct b p;

p.u = k.a;
p.w = k.b;
p.data = (long *) k.c;
```

Your code would most likely run just fine since `long *` and `void *` will *typically* be identically implemented, but why risk it? The standard says stuff like:

> A pointer to void shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a
>   pointer to a character type.39) Similarly, pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of
>   compatible types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements. All
>   pointers to structure types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements
>   as each other. All pointers to union types shall have the same representation and
>   alignment requirements as each other. Pointers to other types need not have the same representation or alignment requirements.

Note the last sentence, where pointers to "other types" (such as `long`) are made distinct from pointers to `void`.

The above is explicit, safe, and much clearer.

Comment: There is (void *)vs(long *) NOT (void *)vs(long).

Comment: how long* and void* can be different sized? Aren't they just pointers? I remember my teacher explaining that the type of a pointer is just used at compile time.. Is he wrong?

Comment: @user1878593 Your teacher is right for a class of platforms, but wrong if the statement is meant to encompass all platforms supported by the C standard. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916051/are-there-are-any-platforms-where-pointers-to-different-types-have-different-siz) for details.

Comment: Independently of this, `void *` is guaranteed to be large enough to hold any *data* pointer, so that a data pointer survives a round-trip to `void *` and back.

Comment: @jacekmigacz Thanks, I mis-read the question. I've edited the answer.