# Why is a pointer to a pointer to a function 8 byte?

Tags: c, function, pointers

I know a pointer to a function is 8 byte because of virtualization but why a pointer to a pointer to a function is 8 byte?

```
typedef void(*fun())();
sizeof(fun*); // returns 8 byte
```

Comment: It's pointers all the way down?  Pointer size is often merely a function of your target's addressing modes.  Your conjecture about virtualization seems unrelated.

Comment: It's entirely possible for pointers of different types to have different sizes, but it's relatively rare. On *most* modern systems, all pointers are the same size (typically 32 or 64 bits).

Comment: Have your verified that this is always the case?  I'm guessing you haven't tried it on an ARM, or 8051, or z80 - IOW, specify your OS and processor target to facilitate correct answers.

Comment: @Keith Thompson  A thought on the idea of _most_.  Embedded processors sell over a billion a year.  Many of these use 16-bit pointers.

Comment: @chux: Good point. Amend that to "most modern processors that novice C programmers are likely to encounter". But isn't it still typical for all pointers on a given system to be the same size?

Comment: @Keith Thompson  Certainly all pointers having same size is a common paradigm.  When different, I most often see the difference between pointers to functions and pointers to data - even today.  C11dr 6.2.5 28 discusses details.

Comment: @KeithThompson - I would venture that more novice C programmers see embedded duty than applicative (IMHO)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have a 64-bit system with 8-bit bytes (and it sounds like you do), probably *all* pointers will be 8 bytes in size.  Virtualization doesn't have anything to do with it.

Comment: Actually, it seems to be the answer. I believed if int is 4 byte then a pointer is also 4 byte, I was wrong. Thanks. I asked about it cuz I read that casting void* to void(*)() is unsafe, so I wanted to overcome that with a pointer to a pointer. So if both pointers are 8 byte then such casting should be safe, am I right? Could it be safe on both x86 and x64?

Comment: Yes, that should be fine.  Casting between data pointers and object pointers isn't supported by the standard, but it will probably work on most implementations.

Comment: @Gospo yes -- you're probably thinking of pointers-to-member; a C++ concept that sometimes requires pointers as long as 4x the length of a void *, in order to support virtual functions and virtual inheritence

Comment: @CarlNorum: You mean “function pointers and object pointers”, not “data pointers and object pointers”.

Answer (score 4):

It's because they're both pointers to memory addresses regardless of what kind of data they point to, and you're running on a 64-bit system

If memory addresses were say... 4 bytes, than it would be impossible to have more than 4GB of ram on your computer.  there just wouldn't be enough different pointer values.

Answer (score 4):

```
pointer to a pointer to a function is 8 byte?
```

it is also a pointer.

`char *, int *, float * and etc` all these pointers Have same size and also function pointer.

Size of pointer is dependent on architecture.

On most architectures Size of pointer is same In your case 8 bytes(64-bit)

on 32-bit  size is 4 bytes,

Adding this based on @ Grijesh Chauhan  comment.

[There have been architectures where pointers to different types have different sizes.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916051/are-there-are-any-platforms-where-pointers-to-different-types-have-different-siz/1539196#1539196)

Comment: `size of any pointer is same.` Not always true. There have been architectures where pointers to different types have different sizes. Read [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1539196/296974)

Answer (score 3):

You have a 64-bit machine with a 64-bit address word, which happens to be 8 bytes.  A pointer is just a memory address, which because of how many bits are in your address space is 8 bytes.

It would be 4 bytes if you were running a 32 bit OS, or 2 bytes on a 286+DOS.

Comment: Pointers are not just memory addresses in all C implementations.

Comment: A fair statement, but until he starts working with microcontrollers or mainframes, focusing on x86 architecture is a useful fiction.