# Fixed-sized pointer type in C99

Tags: c, pointers, portability, c99

I want to create a type to store pointers. The type should be compatible with C99 and have a fixed-width of 64 bits. I came up with several alternatives but they all seem flawed:

- Using `uint64_t` is incorrect since conversions between pointers and integers are implementation-defined [[C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), 6.3.2.3].
- `uinptr_t` also appears to be out of the picture, since the width of this type is not fixed and the type is optional anyway [7.18.1.4].
- Using a struct such as

  ```
  struct {
    #ifdef __LP64__
      void* ptr;
    #else
      // if big endian the following two fields need to be flipped
      void* ptr;
      uint32_t padding; 
    #endif  
  } fixed_ptr_type;
  ```

  does not work either because the size of a pointer is not fixed [even within the same implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916051/are-there-are-any-platforms-where-pointers-to-different-types-have-different-size)

Is there any C99-compatible definition of the type I'm looking for?

Comment: Store pointers? Don't! Unless you're on an embedded system with fixed memory map, on systems with virtual memory (like every modern PS) a single program will just about never have the same memory map even on two consecutive runs.

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: Even though pointer-to-integer conversion is indeed implementation-defined, pointer-to-integer-to-pointer conversion will yield the same pointer (provided the conversion doesn't overflow). If `uintptr_t` isn't good enough, you could try using `uintmax_t`.

Comment: Also, if you store a pointer somewhere, you don't store what it points to, so when you later read the pointer you have a pointer that won't point to what you think it's pointing.

Comment: How can there be a "portable" pointer type that's fixed to 64 bits? What happens when you compile for a 1024-bit processor? (If your answer is "that's ridiculous, nobody needs to plan for that", surely you're essentially saying `uintptr_t` is good enough for real life.)

Comment: The pointer is stored in a struct that is passed to a function. 'Storing' does not mean 'storing for a different run' here

Comment: @Leushenko You are correct, using '64 bits width' and 'portable' in the same statement is contradictory if we consider future architectures.

Comment: Just removed any references to portability

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Object pointers

The best type to store object pointers is `void *`. Any object pointer can be converted to `void *` and back again.

#### Function pointers

A `void *` cannot necessarily store a function pointer. However, any function pointer can be converted to another type of function pointer, so you could store them in some arbitrary type (such as `void (*)(void)`).

#### Padding

I have no idea why you would need your pointer type to have a predetermined size, but you could pad them by using a union and hope that the result is not too large:

```
union fixed_ptr_type {
  void *p;
  char c[64/CHAR_BIT];
};

assert (CHAR_BIT * sizeof (union fixed_ptr_type) == 64);
```

Comment: The problem is indeed you have no guarantee there will be no padding at the end of the union; this even if the size of the array `c` is larger than the size of the `p` pointer.

Comment: @ouah yep, this solution guarantees that _at least_ 64 bits of storage are used in the type representation. What is not clear to me is whether a (non-portable) GCC-pragma such as `__attribute__ ((aligned (64)))` even ensures that the size does not exceed 64 bits - it appears not to be the case.

Comment: This is the most portable answer you're going to get to your question.   You're already assuming that `void *` is 64-bits, you might as well assume that `void *` doesn't need more than 64-bit alignment.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand your objection to using the `void *` with padding. All objects of the same type have the same size. If a different object pointer type has a different size, that doesn't matter, because you convert it to `void *` to store it in your super-pointer.

Regarding `uintptr_t`: If it is not supported , then chances are that it's because there is actually no way of doing this on the particular platform.

So you could use `uintptr_t`. To add in the fixed-width requirement, you could cast to `uintptr_t` then to `uint64_t` (if you're happy with knowing you'll have to change your code when someone puts out a system that has pointers greater than 64bits!)

Comment: The question becomes whether the conversion between `uinptr_t` and `uint64_t` is legal (and let's assume that a pointer cannot be larger than 64 bits, which is admittedly a big caveat to my portability claim), and implementation-independent. I could not find any claim about this in the standard. For instance, sizeof(uintptr_t) _could_ be more than 8 bytes.

Comment: With respect to using `void*` and padding, please see my response to the other suggested solution. Can you enforce that the struct will use exactly 64 bits?

Comment: @user3120046 well it is legal, but it would lose data if the `uintptr_t` was greater than 64bits. That's what I meant by my last sentence.  You stated that you want a fixed-width type. So you have to pick a width.

Comment: You can enforce that the struct will use exactly 64 bits, so long as `void *` is not bigger than that (again, you specified fixed-width so you have to actually specify a width).

Comment: How can you really enforce it? My understanding of the standard is that for a union such as the one suggested by Nisse Engstrom the compiler only ensures that _at least_ 64 bits of storage will be used. But it could more.

Comment: You could do a compile-time `sizeof` check to make sure that it didn't

Answer (score 2):

You cannot portably store pointer values in a 64-bit type. It's perfectly legal for an implementation to use 128-bit pointers.

If you don't mind losing portability to systems with pointers bigger than 64 bits, you can probably get away with using `uint64_t`. Conversions from pointer types to `uint64_t` are not guaranteed to work correctly without losing information, but they will almost certainly do so on any reasonable systems where pointers are no wider than 64 bits.

If an implementation has no 64-bit unsigned integer type without padding bits, then it will not define `uint64_t` at all (for example, a system with 9-bit bytes would not be able to implement `uint64_t`). There's a type `uint_least64_t` that's guaranteed, as the name implies, to be *at least* 64 bits wide; it will be exactly 64 bits on most systems, and wider than 64 bits only on systems where `uint64_t` doesn't exist.

`uintptr_t` is guaranteed to hold a converted `void*` value without loss of information, but it's not guaranteed to exist -- and if it doesn't exist, then *no* integer type can hold a converted `void*` value without loss of information. A conforming implementation needn't necessarily have *any* integer type that can hold a pointer value without loss of information.

Function pointers are another matter. Conversion from a function pointer to `void*`, or to any integer type, has undefined behavior (because the standard doesn't say what the behavior should be).

There simply is no 100% portable way to do what you're trying to do. You'll just have to settle for 99.9% portability. If you're not concerned with function pointers, I'd suggest using `uint64_t` (perhaps defining your own `typedef` to make it clear what you're doing) and add a compile-time or run-time check to confirm that `sizeof (void*) <= sizeof (uint64_t)`. That should cover every existing implementation that I've ever heard of.

It might be helpful to know what your actual goal is. Why do you want to store pointers in no more or less than 64 bits? What problem does this solve that storing them in `void*` objects doesn't solve?

Incidentally, the `__LP64__` macro that you mention in your question is non-standard.

Comment: "Conversions from pointer types to uint64_t [...] will almost certainly [work] on any reasonable systems where pointers are no wider than 64 bits" This is the part where I get lost in the spec. Are conversions between pointers and integers not guaranteed to work because (a) the integer type size might be smaller than the pointer size (b) the conversion might change the representation of the pointer in a implementation-specific manner?  If (b) indeed happens, then even an uint64_t does not work. But I do not know if there is a compiler that does (b)

Comment: They're not guaranteed to work because the standard doesn't guarantee that they work. The only guarantee the standard makes in this area is that conversion from `void*` to `[u]intptr_t` and back to `void*` yields the original `void*` value. Conversion from a pointer type to a larger integer type will *probably* work "correctly", but the standard doesn't require it; it basically provides the minimal set of guarantees that let you do what you need to do. Remember that every guarantee made by the standard is a requirement imposed on all C compilers.

Comment: It probably would have been reasonable for the standard to guarantee that conversion of a pointer type to an integer type and back to the original pointer type yields the original pointer value whenever the integer type's size is at least as large as the pointer type's size, and that's likely true for most or all actual C compilers. But the standard doesn't make that promise -- which gives compiler writes the freedom to violate it if there turns out to be a good reason to do so. (I can't think of a good reason, but ...)

Comment: Just found out a good example of why is not a good idea to converting from pointer to uint64_t...in 32 bits, if the upper-most bit of the pointer is set (i.e. the address is above 2GB) the conversion does sign extension even when it is clear that both the source and the destination are unsigned integers. VS has a [warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235307.aspx) to detect these assignments. In other words, if `ptr` is a pointer in 32 bits-mode, `(uint64_t) ptr` is not guaranteed to be equal to `(uint64_t) ((uintptr_t)ptr)`

Comment: @user3120046: If you're converting a pointer to an integer, how is it clear that the source is an unsigned integer? Pointers are not integers, and as far as C is concerned they are neither signed nor unsigned.