# Should I cast void** return in Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, casting

I compile some code with visual studio 9.0 (2008).

The behave as expected, but when I allocate some 2D array with some hand made
functions, Visual-Studio generates some C4133 warning:

```
void ** alloc_2d(int w, int h, size_t type_size);
void free_d2(void ** mem);

int main (void)
{        
    float ** data;

    /* Here is generated a C4133 warning:
       "incompatible type from void ** to float **" */
    data = alloc_2d(100, 100, sizeof **data);

    /* do things with data */

    /* free data */
    free_2d(data);

    return 0;
}
```

I understand why this warning is generated, but I wonder what I should do to make it quiet.

What should I do?

- Live with the warning?
- Disable the warning (dangerous I think)?
- Disable the warning around the `alloc_2d` calls (with some macros specific to 
  visual studio)?
- cast the function return (But [[Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/1212012]))

Second question:

- Are newer/other compilers aware of this kind of cast?

---

Behind the `void**` are hidden two arrays: one big to store all data I need to be contiguous, and one other to browse through differents lines.

The implementation looks like (I removed the error checking)

```
void **alloc_2D_array(int w, int h, size_t size)
{
    void ** mem = malloc(w * sizeof *mem);
    *mem = malloc(w*h*size);
    for (i = 1; i < w; ++i)
    {
        mem[i] = (void*)((char*)mem[0] + i*w*size);
    }
    return mem;
}
```

Comment: `malloc` returns a `void *`, which is a generic pointer. But your function returns a `void **`, which is not a generic pointer, so you have to cast it.

Comment: Why do you use a pointer of pointer? You may allocate a 2d array using a pointer and simple math computation! How have you written the alloc_2d function? (post it could be intersting to solve your problem).

Comment: I think that it's better to avoid pointers of pointer if they're not strictly usefull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generic pointer type in C is `void*`. That does *not* mean that `void**` is also a generic pointer type, the rule does not apply recursively.

Rather, a conversion from `void**` to `float**` or the other way around is an invalid pointer conversion. They are not compatible types - the compiler must issue a diagnostic message. Ignoring the warning might result in misaligned data or strict aliasing issues - in either case bugs.

---

> What should I do?

Fix the code so that it doesn't contain forbidden pointer conversions.

---

> Are newer/other compilers aware of this kind of cast?

This particular rule has not changed since the first standardization of C.

---

As for how you should fix your code... you shouldn't. You should rewrite it from scratch so that it allocates *arrays* and not "pointer-based look-up tables". There is no obvious reason why you would benefit from such a look-up-table here, but many reasons why you should avoid it.

In addition, your code would be much more readable if you use pointers to VLA.

See [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays) for examples of how to do this proper (code example at the very bottom of the answer).

Comment: (Note that you might have to switch to a standard-compliant C compiler for this to work.)

Comment: Fully agreed on using just one array if possible, but for the VLA you suggest, "*standard compliant*" isn't enough. MSVC is at least compliant to C89, but even if you strictly require compliance with the *latest* standard, VLAs are still *optional*. Therefore it's good to know how to achieve the same without them.

Answer (score 3):

From the signature, I assume your function is implemented roughly like this (plus error checking I'm leaving out here for brevity):

```
void **alloc_2d(int w, int h, size_t type_size)
{
    void **pointers = malloc(h * sizeof *pointers);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < h; ++i)
    {
        pointers[i] = malloc(w * type_size);
    }
    return pointers;
}
```

Some remarks on this:

- The result of this function is **not** a *2d array*, but an array of pointers to arrays. It can be used somewhat similar to a real 2d array, but comes with some overhead. A real 2d array would be **one** contiguous block of size `w * h * type_size`.
- This code is in fact unsafe and could invoke undefined behavior when you cast the `void **` returned from it to `float **`. This is because there's no guarantee that pointers to different types have the same representation -- they could even have different sizes. See also [Are there any platforms where pointers to different types have different sizes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/916051/2371524). By casting `void **` to `float **`, you're treating an array of `void *` *as if it was* and array of `float *`. Although probably fine on your typical modern PC platform, this *can go completely wrong*.

That said, you could avoid the cast by simply having your function return `void *` instead of `void **`, but this would only hide the problem: `void *` is **the** generic pointer type and the compiler will allow implicit conversion to any other pointer type, but you'd still access your `void *` array using the wrong pointer type that way.

---

I suggest allocating a flat array instead and calculate the offsets manually, like this:

```
size_t rows = 100;
size_t cols = 100;
float *data = malloc(cols * rows * sizeof *data);

data[cols*5 + 3] = 1.41;
// ...

free(data);
```

---

As an alternative, you can use variable-length arrays (obligatory in C99, optional but almost always supported in C11 -- *maybe not supported by Microsoft* ....) to dynamically allocate a real *2d array*:

```
size_t rows = 100;
size_t cols = 100;
float (*data)[cols] = malloc(rows * sizeof *data);

data[5][3] = 1.41;
// ...
free(data);
```