# Understanding output of pointer size in C Programming Language

Tags: pointers, memory, printf, sizeof

I am trying to understand why this `printf` statement gives two different outputs; I think I have a decent understanding of one of the outputs.

Here is the code:

```
    const char *ptr = "hello";
    const char array[] = "hello";

   //Question 2
   
    printf("%zu %zu\n", sizeof(ptr),sizeof(array));
```

Now I understand why `sizeof(array)` returns six: this is because the length of `"hello"` is 6 plus an additional null terminator.

But I do not understand why `sizeof(ptr)` is 8; my guess is that all memory addresses in C occupy 8 bits of memory hence the size is 8. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C language, itself, doesn't define what size a pointer is, or [even if all pointers are the same size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/916051/10871073). But, yes, on your platform, the size of a `char*` pointer is 8 bytes.

This is typical on 64-bit platforms (the name implies 64-bit addressing which, with 8 bits per byte, is 64/8 = 8 bytes). For example, when compiling for a Windows 64-bit target architecture, `sizeof(char*)` is 8 bytes; however, when targeting the Windows 32-bit platform, `sizeof(char*)` will be 4 bytes.

Note also that the `"hello"` string literal/array is 6 bytes ***including*** the `nul` terminator.

Comment: I have a small follow up question

What happens when I replace ptr with *ptr and replace array with &array

Why is the size of *ptr 1, is it because it is pointing to the first element in hello string, which has size 1?

I understand why &array is 8

Comment: @KhandkarIslam Yes, `sizeof(*ptr)` will yield the size of a `char` (which is **defined** by the C Standard to be 1 byte). And `&array` is also a pointer, which also has a size of bytes (on your platform).

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(ptr)` returns 8 because it's the size of a pointer on a typical 64-bit architecture. The pointer ptr is a pointer to a constant character, so its size is 8 bytes on a 64-bit system. The value stored in the pointer is the memory address of the first character in the string literal `"hello"`, so `ptr` takes up 8 bytes of memory, not 6.

The size of a pointer is platform-dependent and can be different on different architectures. On a 32-bit system, the size of a pointer would typically be 4 bytes.

Comment: It's worth noting that the size of a pointer has no relation to the size of the thing it points to.