# Does a pointer also have any address or memory allocation?

Tags: c, pointers

If a pointer stores the address of a variable ... then from where do we get the pointer?

What I asked was that if we are using pointer directly, then there must be a location from where we get this pointer?

Comment: Retagged post. Ruby? Come on.

Comment: As it stands, you question hardly makes sense.

Comment: I pretty much answered your question, and a couple others showed you examples. Is there something else you need?

Comment: You get the pointer from an API or another variable. If you don't initialize or assign a value to a particular pointer, it can point anywhere.

In other words, your intuition is correct: the pointer value has to come from somewhere.

Comment: Replace API with function in my comment.

Answer (score 30):

Yes, a declared pointer has its own location in memory.

[image]

In the example above, you have a variable, 'b', which stores the value "17".

```
int b = 17;    /* the value of 'b' is stored at memory location 1462 */
```

When you create a **pointer to that variable**, the pointer is **stored in its own memory location**.

```
int *a;
a = &b;       /* the pointer 'a' is stored at memory location 874 */
```

It is the compiler's job to know where to "get the pointer." When your source code refers to the pointer 'a', the compiler translates it into -> "whatever address value is stored in memory location 874".

*Note: This diagram isn't technically correct since, in 32-bit systems, both pointers and int's use four bytes each.*

Comment: What about pointers to NULL fields? Specifically in recursive abstract data types. -- I'm learning about linked lists. A linked list is effectively an infinite number of pointers (recursive nodes). Do those take up memory? Or do null values not take up memory?

Answer (score 12):

Yes.  Below I have an int and a pointer to an int and code to print out each one's memory address.

```
int a;
printf("address of a: %x", &a);

int* pA = &a;
printf("address of pA: %x", &pA);
```

Pointers, on 32bit systems, take up 4 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

In C:

```
char *p = "Here I am";
```

`p` then stores the address where 'H' is stored. `p` is a variable. You can take a pointer to it:

```
char **pp = &p;
```

`pp` now stores the address of `p`. If you wanted to get the address of `pp` that would be `&pp` etc etc.

Answer (score 3):

Look at this SO post for a better understanding of pointers.
[What are the barriers to understanding pointers and what can be done to overcome them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727/what-are-the-barriers-to-understanding-pointers-and-what-can-be-done-to-overcome)

As far as your question goes, if I understand what you want, then, basically, when you declare a pointer, you specify an address or a numeric index that is assigned to each unit of memory in the system (typically a byte or a word). The system then provides an operation to retrieve the value stored in the memory at that address.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler deals with translating the variables in our code into memory locations used in machine instructions.

The location of a pointer variable depends on where it is declared in the code, but programmers usually don't have to deal with that directly.

A variable declared inside a function lives on the stack or in a register, (unless it is declared static).

A variable declared at the top level lives in a section of memory at the top of the program.

A variable declared as part of a dynamically allocated struct or array lives on the heap.

The `&` operator returns the memory location of the variable, but unlike the `*` operator, it can't be repeated.

For example, `***i` gets the value at the address `**i`, which is the value at address `*i`, which is the value stored in `i`, which the compiler figures out how to find.

But `&&i` won't compile. `&i` is a number, which is the memory location the compiler uses for the variable `i`. This number is not stored anywhere, so `&&i` makes no sense.

(Note that if `&i` is used in the source code, then the compiler can't store `i` in a register.)